# C program character return incorrect value

Tags: pointers, return, character

This code returns correct pointer address to main function but output is faulty

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char* ret();
int main()
{
    char *na;
    na = ret();
    printf("%s \n",na);
    return 0;
}
char* ret()
{
    char c[15],*p;
    scanf("%s",c);
    p = c;
    return p;
}
```

This gives wrong output in Code block with GNU GCC compiler.

when i give an input "goods" output produced is goo£Í"

Comment: *`char c[15]="Hello1234"`* - make it `static`. As it stands, the string and the pointer you return are not valid after the function returns (some hand waiving).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is returning a pointer to a static local variable safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453696/is-returning-a-pointer-to-a-static-local-variable-safe)

Comment: what if i want to get a dynamic string using scanf instead of a static string?

Comment: `static` is actually referring to a storage class; and not static versus dynamic strings. With respect to a storage class, it essentially means the string and its pointer survive the return from a function call. Put another way, the string and its pointer are still valid after the function call.

Comment: Your recent edits just changed the question. Its not longer the same question that was asked, and the comments no longer apply. You should probably ask a new question so the old question and comments remain coherent.

Comment: The Question is same as before i just edited the code. it only produce 3 correct character from the string and excess all are garbage and when i increase the (char c) value to 100 it produce correct output but for above array size it produce wrong output

Comment: I don't believe the question is the same as before. Previously, you had *`char c[15]="Hello1234`* that's no longer present. And now there's a `scanf` that was not part of the original question. /EOM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)