# Building char array from a string (C)

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, types

I am writing a simple function in C that should build a char array from string "abc" – so it should build {'a','b','c'} – and return a pointer to that array. Here is my code for this function:

```
char * makeArr()
{
    static char arr[3];

    sprintf(arr, "%s\n", "abc");

    return arr;
}
```

Problems occur when I call this method in main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *arr[3];

    arr = makeArr();

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler is complaining about casting / conflicting types. I've been playing with pointers, casting and dereferencing for quite a while now, but can't seem to get it to work. Please let me know where my logic is wrong.

Comment: `char *arr[3]` is an array of three `char *`. `makeArr` returns one `char *`, not an array of three of them. And incidientally, `"abc\n"` is four characters long, five with the null terminator, so you shouldn't be trying to write it into a buffer of size 3.

Comment: @hobbs Updated my buffer size to have more than enough space.

Comment: You forget a semicolon after `sprintf(arr, "%s\n", "abc")`.

Comment: This code is wrong on so many levels...

Comment: Returning a pointer to stack-allocated memory from a function is undefined behavior. You need to either pass in your pointer or dynamically allocate the space.

Comment: Note: a pointer to 10-element `char` array can be written like this: `char (*ptr)[10];`

Comment: @wickstopher The `arr` in `makeArr()` is `static` and returning it may not be good behavior but it doesn't seem invalid.

Comment: @MikeCAT you're right, I spoke too soon. it still seems like bad form. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453696/is-returning-a-pointer-to-a-static-local-variable-safe

Comment: @user3413460 please don't change *meaning* of code after you posted a question, that would be confusing to readers of comments and answers. If you want to present "corrected" code, append it in an edit. rolled back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm ... there are *several* errors in this code. Let's start with the most obvious your compiler complains about:

```
char *arr[3];
```

This line declares `arr` to be an array of three **pointers** to `char`. What you return from your function is a single pointer to a `char` -> doesn't match.

Next:

```
static char arr[3];
sprintf(arr, "%s\n", "abc")
```

Here you reserve 3 `char`s. the `sprintf()` will write 5 `char`s. `%s` is replaced by the 3 characters in your *string literal* `"abc"`. You add a newline character and then a `0` is added as the marker for the end of the "string". Makes 5. This btw is *undefined behavior*. You write past the end of your array. Code like this *can* be compiled, but there's no guarantee at all about what will happen at runtime.

---

Doing a *cut* here. You should read about arrays and pointers in C. If the text you're reading claims they are the same ... stop right there and find a better text. They aren't.

I'll try to explain this here briefly, so it's suitable for the *Q&A* style.

An array in C indeed is a contiguous space of several values. `char arr[3]` means a variable that holds 3 `char`s.

On the other hand, a `char *` is just a pointer pointing to a `char` -- this *could* be the first element of an array.

In C, you can't pass arrays as function parameters, and you can't return arrays from a function. Trying to do so leads to an implicit conversion: What **is** actually passed is a pointer to the first element of that array.

I think the last bit of information missing is what a *string literal* in C is: it's an array (anonymous, e.g., it doesn't have a name) containing all the characters in the double quotes *plus* a `0` appended. The `0` marks the end of a "string" in C.

In an expression, a *string literal* evaluates to a pointer to the first element.

So, something like this:

```
char *foo = "bar";
```

will lead to `foo` pointing to the `b` of the array. It's like writing

```
static const char no_name_0[] = { 'b', 'a', 'r', 0 };
char *foo = &(no_name_0[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Among other things, you confused:

`char arr[3]; // array of 3 chars.`

and,

`char *arr[3];   // array of 3 pointers to char.`

In main(), you should only write `char *arr;`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `char arr[3];` is too snall to store `"abc\n"`. It must have at least 5 elements including terminating null-character.

Then, `char *arr[3];` is a 3-element array of `char*`.
You should assign `makeArr()`'s return value (it has `char*` type) to `arr[0]` or another element, or you should change the type of `arr` in `main` function to `char*`, which is the same type as `makeArr()`'s return value.

Moreover, this `makeArr()` doesn't make any array and returns (a pointer to) the existing array. Yoy should use `malloc()` to "make an array".

**UPDATE:**

Assigning a value of `char*` to the array `char arr[10];` seems invalid in C.
You should use `strcpy()` or `strncpy()` (safer than `strcpy()`) to copy the string stored in the array between arrays.

Comment: Updated buffer size to 10

Answer (score 0):

Pass the array as an argument and modify it in the called function, would be easier. If you're statically creating the array and there's no need to allocate memory, don't, just pass around your pointers to the functions to be modified by reference

```
void makeArr(char arr[]){
    sprintf(arr, "%s\n", "abc");
}
```

Simply pass the existing declared array to the makeArr function...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char arr[10];
  makeArr(arr);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't assign the result of makeArr to arr.  I guess that's your casting error.  Oversimplifying, arr points to the place on the stack where the array of 10 characters is allocated.  So, I'd pass in arr to makeArr as a char*.  So, you'd end up with something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char * makeArr(char *arr)
{
    sprintf(arr, "%s\n", "abc");
    return arr;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char arr[10];

    makeArr(arr);
    printf("%s\n", arr);
    return 0;
}
```