# How to use sprintf with char pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, char, printf

What is wrong with the function. How come nothing gets printed out?

```
char * CombineStr(char * str1, char * str2)
{
    char strOut[256];
    sprintf(strOut, “%s%s”, str1, str2);
    return strOut;
}
```

Comment: UB? You are allocating strout in stack and returning a pointer to a location that is "deallocated" on function return.

Comment: @Amadeus locals are allocated in stack not in heap.

Comment: @Serhio thanks right thought, wrong write

Comment: Actually, locals are allocated from static memory. The stack is merely a common implementation of static memory.

Comment: Whatever. `strOut` is no longer in scope after the function returns.

Comment: Another bad thing is that you are using beautified quotes, a.k.a. smart quotes instead of plain quotes in your sprint statement. Try `sprintf(strOut, "%s%s", str1, str2);`

Answer (score 3):

You should take care of scope (storage duration of your variable): either declare returned variable as static, or allocate it dynamically on the heap, using `malloc`, and `free`ing the allocated memory pointed to by `strOut`, once not needed anymore. You should use plain quotes in the format of your `sprintf` second argument. You should take care against overflow.
either:

```
char * CombineStr(char * str1, char * str2)
{
    static char strOut[256];                 //scope!
    if((strlen(str1) + strlen(str2)) < 256)
        sprintf(strOut, "%s%s", str1, str2); //plain quotes!
    return strOut;
}
```

or:

```
char * CombineStr(char * str1, char * str2)
{
    char strOut = malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1);               
    if( strOut != NULL )
        sprintf(strOut, "%s%s", str1, str2); //plain quotes!
    return strOut;
}
```

For further reading, please take a look at following SO posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453696/is-returning-a-pointer-to-a-static-local-variable-safe), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824342/returning-a-local-variable-from-function-in-c).

Comment: Hack with `static` won't work well if user decides to call `CombineStr()` few times and use cached results later. And what about multithreading environment?

Comment: Thanks @Serhio. Added example with dynamic allocation as well.

Answer (score 2):

Another common solution is to have the caller provide the output buffer

```
char * CombineStr(const char * str1, 
                  const char * str2, 
                  char * strOut, 
                  size_t outlen)
{
    size_t len = snprintf(strOut, outlen, "%s%s", str1, str2);
    if (len < outlen)
    {
        return strOut;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Note the switch  from `sprintf` to `snprintf` to prevent buffer overflow should the concatenated string exceed the length of the buffer. This allows us to catch the overflow and return an invalid result to let the caller know `buffer` cannot be trusted.

Typical usage would be

```
char buffer[256];
if (CombineStr("I's the b'y that builds the boat", 
               "And I's the b'y that sails her", 
               buffer,
               sizeof(buffer)) != NULL)
{
    // use buffer
}
```

It needs to be noted that `snprintf` has wonky support and cannot always be trusted to have been null terminated, but you can be sure that it didn't overflow the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Change to `static char strOut[256];`. It is not very good solution but will work.

Comment: Drawbacks of such approach should be described IMO.

Comment: @Serhio The drawback is that static buffer is only one and if someone is using `CombineStr` for example in `sprintf` as 2 or more parameters (2+ calls), the result will be wrong. For that reason my solution is simple and working but not for all cases.