# printing c string pointer

Tags: c, string

I am having problems when it comes to printing/displaying a `char *string`

This is my string

```
    char *messageForServer = ("netsvr type0 dobrien %s- %s",inet_ntoa(clientAddr.sin_addr),port);
```

and when I go to print it like

```
printf("%s\n",messageForServer);
```

it will only print the `port` part of the string.
Will be greatfull for any help as it is bugging me for hours and cant seem to find an answer

Comment: What sort of magic were you expecting?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly....can you explain here

Comment: Maybe you should show some sample output, and explain how this differs from what you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
char messageForServer[100];
sprintf(messageForServer, "netsvr type0 dobrien %s- %s", "something", "8080");
printf("%s\n", messageForServer);
```

UPD: which prints the following

```
netsvr type0 dobrien something- 8080
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is - well, the way you try to get a formatted string has nothing to do with string formatting in C. See [Creating C formatted strings (not printing them)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804288/creating-c-formatted-strings-not-printing-them) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In C, a `char *` can be created and initialized by assigning a string literal:

```
char *string = {"some text here"};
```

It will not understand the initializer you tried,

```
("netsvr type0 dobrien %s- %s",inet_ntoa(clientAddr.sin_addr),port);
```

for at least two reasons:  *1)* because it contains more than a literal string, and *2)*, the `( )` enclosures are syntactically wrong (use `{ }` instead).

If you want to create a string comprised of more than simple text (i.e. a string literal), say for example a string comprised of two strings, an integer and a float, you can do it this way:

char string[NUM_CHAR];

```
sprintf(string, "%s %d %s %f", "Example of string with ", 4, "elements, including the float:", 3.15);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do here is provide a reusable function to print a "message for server" at various points in your code.  You might consider doing exactly that: define a `messageForServer()` function as opposed to your attempt at a pre-formatted string.

```
void messageForServer(char *msg, char *code)
{
    printf("netsvr type0 dobrien %s - %s\n", msg, code);
}
```

Simple.  Clean.  Reusable.