# Returning structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

This is probably a really stupid question, but

I have an array of structs outside of int main

```
typedef struct{
    char c;
    int k;
}factor_t;
```

and I declared

```
factor_t *factors = malloc(INIT*sizeof(*factors));
```

where `INIT` is 10

After running my function, I have an array of structs each which holds a char, `c`, and integer, `k` - e.g., `factors[5].c` could hold `"b"` or `"d"` or `"e"` and `factors[5].k` could hold `"3"` or `"33"` or `"333"`

I need to somehow insert these into a string, but I can't seem to

```
strcat(destination,c or k);
```

they both give me pointer to integer errors, destination is a `char*`

How would I go about putting these into a string? I'm aiming to get a string that looks like

```
ck
ck
ck
```

that is, a pattern of `"ck\n"` per struct, where `c` = char and `k` = integer

I use `strcat(destination, "\n");` for the `\n` and it works, but I can't do the same with `c` and `k`

Comment: "factors[5].c could hold "b" ... " No! `factors[5].c` holds `'b'`. If you do not see the difference read about character constants and string literals. And `factors[5].k` holds `333`, not `"333"`.

Comment: Just had a quick read, sorry about that - my bad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating C formatted strings (not printing them)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804288/creating-c-formatted-strings-not-printing-them)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sprintf`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm) to do so . -

```
size_t len=strlen(destination);         // calculate before concatenation
sprintf(&destination[len], "%c%d\n", factors[5].c,factors[5].k);   // string with newline
```

`destination` should be of type `char *`.

Comment: This coe will overwrite `destination` not concatenate.

Comment: @MikeCAT Hmm , string with newline in it ? What does he will do with that .

Comment: @chux  Ohh , sorry .Big mistake .Completely forgot that while typing . Thanks for pointing out .

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the length of the string and output with that offset.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char c;
    int k;
}factor_t;

void struct_cat(char *str, factor_t f) {
    sprintf(str + strlen(str), "%c%d", f.c, f.k);
}

int main(void) {
    factor_t fac = {'b', 33};
    char buf[100] = "hogehoge";
    struct_cat(buf, fac);
    puts(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: be advised that `buf[100]` might not be big enough to store all values: 10 * a minimum of 3 chars (eg `'a'` + `'1'` + `'\n'`), with a max of 12 chars (`'a'` + `'2147483647'` (`INT_MAX`) + `'\n'`) -> you'll probably want `buf[121]` to be safe

Answer (score 2):

`strcat` appends a copy of the source string to the destination string. It expects `c` to be a null terminated string not a single `char`

If you want to add a single `char` to an array that is larger than `n` and the null terminating char is at index `n`

```
destination[n] = c;
destination[n+1] = '\0;
```

you have to be certain that `destination` is large enough.

If you want to format print additional data to destination string, again make sure destination is large enough and do :

```
sprintf(destination + n, "%c%d\n", c, k);
```

Or if you know how that destination has `m` chars left :

```
snprintf(destination + n, m, "%c%d\n", c, k);
```

With this if you attempt to print more than `m` chars the extra ones will be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

If you need separate this feature use function (like @MikeCAT). But use of `snprintf()` and `strncat()` does not allow to go beyond the array bounds:

```
void strncat_struct(char *buffer, size_t buffer_size, factor_t f)
{
    char tmp_buf[32];
    snprintf(tmp_buf, sizeof(tmp_buf), "%c, %d\n", f.c, f.k);
    strncat(buffer, tmp_buf, buffer_size);
}

int32_t main(int32_t argc, char **argv)
{
//...
    char buffer[256] = {0};
    for(i = 0; i < INIT; i++) {
        strncat_struct(buffer, sizeof(buffer), factors[i]);
    }
//...
}
```

Without using additional function. It is theoretically faster, couse there is no need to calculate string length:

```
int32_t main(int32_t argc, char **argv)
{
//...
    char buffer[256];
    char *buf_ptr = buffer;
    size_t buf_size = sizeof(buffer);
    for(i = 0; i < INIT; i++) {
        int32_t printed;
        printed = snprintf(buf_ptr, buf_size, "%c, %d\n", factors[i].c, factors[i].k);
        buf_ptr += printed;
        buf_size -= printed;
    }
//...
}
```