# unable to compile program due to function asprintf

Tags: c

Found this code, it needed to stop throttling the CPU to 20% in Dell laptops, which occurs due to the power adapter failing to be recognized by the computer.

Tried to compile on Kubuntu and got this:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘asprintf’; did you mean ‘vasprintf’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   47 |   if (asprintf(&concat_cmd, "%s %i", cmd, *reg_value) == -1)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
      |       vasprintf
```

I don’t understand why it is happening. I read that `asprintf` is part of the **libiberty-dev**. The library is installed but everything does not work. Also I added

```
#include <libiberty/libiberty.h>
```

and got the same - implicit declaration of function ‘asprintf’

tell me what to do with it?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <libiberty/libiberty.h>

#define BUFSIZE (64)

int get_msr_value(uint64_t *reg_value) {
  const char *cmd = "rdmsr -u 0x1FC";
  char cmd_buf[BUFSIZE];

  FILE *fp;

  if ((fp = popen(cmd, "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening pipe!\n");
    return -1;
  }

  cmd_buf[strcspn(fgets(cmd_buf, BUFSIZE, fp), "\n")] = 0;
  *reg_value = atoi(cmd_buf);

  if (pclose(fp)) {
    printf("Command not found or exited with error status\n");
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  const char *cmd = "wrmsr -a 0x1FC";
  char *concat_cmd;
  int ret;
  uint64_t *reg_value = &(uint64_t){ 0 };

  if ((ret = get_msr_value(reg_value))) {
    return ret;
  }

  printf("Old register value: %lu\n", *reg_value);

  *reg_value = *reg_value & 0xFFFFFFFE;  // clear bit 0

  printf("New register value: %lu\n", *reg_value);

  if (asprintf(&concat_cmd, "%s %i", cmd, *reg_value) == -1)
    return -1;

  printf("Executing: %s\n", concat_cmd);

  system(concat_cmd);
  free(concat_cmd);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: probably there is a `#define asprintf` in effect there.  That is, `asprintf` has already been defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

asprintf is part of stdio.h, but you need to add `#define _GNU_SOURCE` at the top of your file and use `-std=gnu99` when compiling.

Comment: This answer only applies to Gnu-based systems (i.e.Linux). But it's correct for those. +1

Comment: Even with #define _GNU_SOURCE  and -std=gnu99, I'm still seeing these errors on Raspberry Pi.  It is wrapped in "#if __GLIBC_USE (LIB_EXT2)", so I have to do "#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2__ 1".

Comment: Strangely it only worked for me with #define __GNU_SOURCE  *and* -D_GNU_SOURCE passed to gcc.

Answer (score 2):

The function `asprintf()` is not yet part of the C Standard. It is available in the GNU libc and most likely supported on your system since it uses this C library, with a declaration in `<stdio.h>`.

You might need to define `__GNU_SOURCE` or `__USE_GNU` before including `<stdio.h>` for this declaration to be parsed by the compiler.  Run `man asprintf` to see which feature macro to use or look inside the file `/usr/include/stdio.h` on your system.

Either modify the source code or add a `-D__GNU_SOURCE` command line argument in your `CFLAGS` in the Makefile.

Comment: For newer distros, it seems to be `#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2 1`.