# Making fstring (Python) in C

Tags: c

I want to make a url in C to send a post request using libcurl, and I want to change it frequently something like this:

> url="http://website.com/"
> keyword="this parameter should be changed each time!"
> auth="username:password"

I have been using C for about 2 months and before that I wrote such codes using Python; in Python, I used to write this things with fstrings, but now I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Perhaps [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) might be useful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating C formatted strings (not printing them)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804288/creating-c-formatted-strings-not-printing-them)

Answer (score 1):

In C, you can achieve similar functionality to Python's `f-strings` by using formatted string functions like `sprintf` or `snprintf`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char url[200]; // Adjust the size based on your expected URL length
    char keyword[] = "this parameter should be changed each time!";
    char auth[] = "username:password";

    // Formating String using the function
    snprintf(url, sizeof(url), "http://website.com/?keyword=%s&auth=%s", keyword, auth);

    printf("URL: %s\n", url);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but when I make a URL and place it in curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, URL); it does not work! it shows **closing connection -1** I check the -1 error in the documentation and I do not get why this is happening in my case!! and how to fix it