# C variable argument refactoring

Tags: c, function, refactoring

I have a function `irc_sendline` that can be called like `printf` can

```
irc_sendline(s, "A strange game.\nThe only %s is not to play.", "winning move");
```

It works perfectly, but I'm not happy with its implementation:

```
int irc_sendline(irc *iobj, char *msg, ...)
{
   char tmp_msg[BUFSIZE], fmsg[BUFSIZE];
   va_list args;
   int len;

   va_start(args, msg);

   strncpy(tmp_msg, msg, BUFSIZE);
   strncat(tmp_msg, "\r\n", BUFSIZE);

   len = vsnprintf(fmsg, BUFSIZE, tmp_msg, args);
   len = send(iobj->fd, fmsg, len, 0);

   return len;
}
```

You see, I'm using 2 "temporary" buffers here, because I first have to copy the original message from the function arguments to a temporary buffer to append "\r\n" to it, and then copy that temporary buffer to **another** temporary buffer to do the actual formatting with the arguments supplied from the function call, and only *THEN* I can send the stuff on its way.

How could I make this cleaner, better?

---

Thanks for all the input here, I thought my only problem was the mess in there, but it was actually a ticking timebomb! My new function looks like this:

```
int irc_sendline(irc *iobj, char *msg, ...)
{
   char buffer[BUFSIZE];
   va_list args;
   int res_str_len;
   int sent;

   va_start(args, msg);

   res_str_len = vsnprintf(buffer, BUFSIZE, msg, args);

   sent =  send(iobj->fd, buffer, res_str_len, 0);
   sent += send(iobj->fd, "\r\n", 2, 0);

   return sent;
}
```

If I could, I'd accept multiple answers here, but meh.

Comment: Your code is broken because of the incorrect use of `strncpy` (see my answer).

Comment: Your use of `strncat` is also broken. `strncat` does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First use `vsnprintf` to format the data, then append the "\r\n" to the result from that. Alternatively, just use a second call to `send` to sent the "\r\n".

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, if you are interested in "cleaner", stop using `strncpy`. Despite the misleading name (and contrary to the popular belief), this is not a limited-length string copying function. It is safe to say that `strncpy` is a function that has virtually no practical uses today. When you see `strncpy` used in the code, "cleaner" immediately becomes out of question (aside from the disappearingly narrow set of the cases `strncpy` was actually intended to be used for).

In fact, your code is broken specifically because you used `strncpy`: if the length of the format string is greater than the length of the buffer, `strncpy` *does not append the terminating null character* to the result, meaning that the subsequent `strncat` call will crash (at best).

The limited length copying function does not exist in the standard library, but it is often provided by the implementation under the name `strlcpy`. If the implementation you are using does not provide one - write one yourself and use it.

Your code is also broken because of the incorrect use of `strncat`: `strncat` does not take the length of the full buffer as the last argument. Instead, `strncat` expects the length of the available *remainder* of the buffer. So, if you want to use `strncat`, you have to calculate first how much space was left at the end of the buffer after the previous copying. Again, even though `strncat` is more useful than `strncpy`, you might be better off using the non-standard (but often provided by the implementation) function `strlcat`, which actually works the way you thought `strncat` worked.

Secondly, instead of adding the `\r\n` part in advance, why don't you do it afterwards? Use the fact that `vsnprintf` returns the number of characters written into the output buffer and simply append the `\r`, the `\n` and `\0` characters at the end after `vsnprintf` finished working. You don't have to use `strncat` for that purpose. Just write the characters into the buffer directly, making sure, of course, that you don't cross the boundary.

Comment: Thanks for the warning (3 of them actually :), I'm currently looking up on this issue, and it seems like I have to write my own strlcpy, because Linux doesn't provide it. On the strncpy matter - so it's broken because it won't append \NUL when the target string is longer/as long as the destination string?

Comment: Firstly, yes, it does not append `\0` if string is longer. Secondly, it fills the entire remainder of the buffer with zeros if the string is shorter, which is completely unnecessary. Once again, `strncpy` is not a function that was created for null-terminated strings. It is a function that was created for a completely different purpose - to support so called "fixed width" strings in some old version of Unix file system. You can read more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453876/why-does-strncpy-not-null-terminate

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up, now I remember why I explicitly zero-terminated my strings in some other programs that used strncpy.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `\r\n` is going to end up at the end of the formatted string, why not copy afterwards:

```
va_start(args, msg);
len = vsnprintf(fmsg, BUFSIZE, msg, args);
strncat(fmsg, "\r\n", BUFSIZE - strlen(fmsg) - 1);
```

Note that I also fixed the arguments to strncat.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you wanted to use msg for the strcat (unsafe and evil because you don't know the string size), I think you are going to have to live with 2 buffers.

As an aside, I'd consider strncpy(..., BUFSIZE-2) so that the \r\n always makes it onto your messages and therefore strings always wrap.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the BUFSIZE thing! I didn't notice that at all, could have screwn me over.

Comment: You are still forgetting that `stncpy` does not add the null-terminator to the string if the buffer is too short. `BUFSIZE-2` will not fix that. Your code will crash every time the buffer end is hit by the format string.

Answer (score 0):

One major problem with your code -- vsnprintf returns the number of characters that would be placed in the buffer if it was infinitely large, which may be larger than BUFSIZE if the buffer is not big enough.  So if you have a message that overflows, you'll end up sending random garbage from after the end of your buffer.  You need to add a line

```
if (res_str_len >= BUFSIZE) res_str_len = BUFSIZE-1
```

after the vprintf if you want to actually truncate the message