# Error:incompatible types in assignment of 'const char[5]' to 'char[10]'

Tags: c++, char

I have defined c as

```
char c[][10]
```

in function definition and used it like `c[i]="gray";`

Whats wrong? I searched on net, it shows the same syntax.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, what warning or error are you seeing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot use assignment (`=`) on an array.  If you change `c` to an array of pointers, that might work, depending on what you need to do with it.

```
const char *c[20];
c[i] = "gray";
```

Or if the declared type must be array of arrays, you could use `strncpy`:

```
char c[20][10];
strncpy(c[i], "gray", sizeof(c[i]));
```

Comment: Do not use `strncpy`!  It can potentially leave you with non-null-terminated strings.

Answer (score 15):

The problem is that arrays are not assignable in C.  String constants like `"gray"` are character array constants: in this case, the type is `char[5]` (4 + 1 for the terminating null).

If you know that the destination array is large enough to hold the desired string, you can use [`strcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to copy the string like so:

```
// Make sure you know that c[i] is big enough!
strcpy(c[i], "gray");
```

A better idea is to use a safer function such as [`strlcpy`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=strlcpy&sektion=3) (BSD-based systems and Mac OS X) or [`strcpy_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (Windows):

```
strlcpy(c[i], "gray", 10);  // 10 is the size of c[i]
```

However, these functions are platform-specific and not all that portable.  You could also roll your own implementation if speed is not an issue:

```
size_t strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t size)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    while(size > 1 && *src)
    {
        *dst++ = *src++;
        size--;
        len++;
    }
    if(size > 0)
        *dst = 0;
    return len + strlen(src);    
}
```

Do **not** use `strncpy`, since [it could potentially leave you with a non-null-terminated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453876/why-does-strncpy-not-null-terminate)

Comment: strlcpy ?? did you mean ‘strncpy’? typo there, (edit queue is full)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `strcpy()` (found in the `cstring` header) instead of just plain assignment.

Answer (score 1):

this code will work and make the correct assignements in 3 different ways:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string myString = "hello my friends from Brazil";
    char charOut[myString.size()];
    strncpy(charOut, myString.c_str(), myString.size());
    std::cout << "Char by strncpy string var  " << charOut << std::endl;

    const char *charOut2;
    charOut2 = "sup my homies in L.A.";
    std::cout << "Char by const  " << charOut2 << std::endl;

    string myString2 = "hallo mein bruder in Berlin";
    char charOut3[myString2.size()];
    strcpy(charOut3, myString2.c_str());
    std::cout << "Char by strcpy string var  " << charOut3 << std::endl;
}
```

runs ok on ubuntu servers.  did not test on other systems.