# Creating a string with char[]

Tags: c++, string, char

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char strin[206];

    strin = "sds";
    cout<<strin;
}
```

Why do I get this error?

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of 'const char [4]' to 'char [206]' //on line strin = "sds"
```

I am following [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson9.html) beginner tutorial

Comment: Use : `strcpy`. Oh wait why not simply use `std::string`?

Comment: Hehe, Ankur asks "why" and everybody answers "what to do" :)

Comment: I recommend ignoring that tutorial. It is... how to put this in nice wor-- nevermind the nice words. It is terrible. You won't learn C++ from it.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5414186/938236

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes +1. I'd just add that for learning C++, SO keeps a list of [good books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @Angew Thanks for the link. I like it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that you're trying to assign one array into another. The assignment operator can't do that; you'd have to copy the array using `strcpy()` or `std::copy()`.

However, since you want to work in C++, you should really be using `std::string` instead of `char[]` to store strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can not assign an array to another directly. It should be copied element to element.

Use [`std::strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) from [`<cstring>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring) header

```
char strin[206];
std::strcpy(strin, "sds");
```

Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) from [`<string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string) header

```
std::string strin;
strin = "sds";
```

Since you're using C++, choose second one.

Answer (score 1):

Your code;

```
strin = "sds";
```

should be:

```
strcpy(strin, "sds");
```

Answer (score 0):

C/C++ doesn't have string opertions built-in. You need to use either function:

```
strcpy(strin, "sds"); // will work in C and C++
// strncpy(strin, "sds", 205); // safer if you want to copy user-given string
```

or `std::string`:

```
std::string strin(206, 0);

strin = "sds"; // only C++
```

Answer (score 0):

**strin** is a array which is a **const** pointer to **chars**, not a pointer to **chars**.
You tried to change the **const** pointer and this is forbidden

you need to copy the string. e.g. this way

```
strcpy (string, "sds");
```

(Aware buffer overflows in general cases!)

Comment: So what i understood is that when copying an array, you do not actually clone the array but just get a reference to the original array, is that right?

Comment: `xys = "123"` does not copy, it just changes the pointer (if allowed). In this way it is right