# Changing values of an array containing a struct printing

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I would like to access the name field from the array items and print the name but I am having trouble.

I created a pointer 'L' in callInitialize and set it to the upper struct type List which I named 'studentList'.

```
int callInitialize () {

/*Initialize a List*/
List studentList;
List *L;
L = &studentList;
Initialize(L);

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("L->count after function call Initialize = %d\n", L->count);
    printf("L->items[0].name after function call Initialize = %s\n", studentList.items[0].name);
#endif 

return 0;
}
```

I then called Initialize and tried to set the value to test but this is incorrect.

```
void Initialize (List *L) {
char test = "I like you";
L->count = 0;
L->items[0].name = test;
}
```

I am unsure of why L->items[0].name = test; is not appropriate. I am getting an incompatible types error but name is char and test is char?

Also, once I do change that value how would I print that? My thinking was that %s would be correct since the type of the field name is char. Print is above in callIntialize as a debug statement.

My struct declarations:

```
#define MAXNAMESIZE 20
typedef struct {
char name[MAXNAMESIZE];
int grade;   
} Student;

typedef Student Item;
#define MAXLISTSIZE 4
typedef struct {
Item items[MAXLISTSIZE];
int count;
} List;
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String copying in C doesn't work like that.  Strings are simply arrays of characters, with a null character as the last element used; so to copy a string you need to copy the individual characters from the source array to the corresponding elements in the destination array.  There are library functions for doing this, such as `strncpy()`.

So you would need to change:

```
L->items[0].name = test;
```

..to something like:

```
strncpy(L->items[0].name,test,MAXNAMESIZE);
L->items[0].name[MAXNAMESIZE - 1] = '\0';
```

..where the second line just makes sure there's a null character at the end, in case `test` was longer than `MAXNAMESIZE`.

If the `name` member of `Student` had been declared as a `char *` and allocated with `malloc()`, rather than declared as an array of `char`, the assignment would have worked, but probably not done what you wanted -- it would have changed `name` to point to the same string as `test` (not a copy of it) and just discarded the original value, leaking the `malloc()`ed memory.

Comment: [`strncpy` does not necessarily null-terminate your strings!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453876/why-does-strncpy-not-null-terminate)

Comment: @AdamRosenfield That's why the answer explicitly null terminates it after `strncpy`