# if (* ptr)[variable] means "pointer to an array", what does mean (* ptr)[variable] = '\0'?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, getline, getchar

the code below works in the following way: it basically reads every single char from the `stdin` using a function called `_getchar`, allocates them in an array which finally ends up returning it if `c =! EOF`.

I'd like to just know what's doing the statement `(*lineptr)[n_read] = '\0';` in the code below:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int _getchar(void)
{
    int rd;
    char buff[2];

    rd = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, 1);

    if (rd == 0)
        return (EOF);
    if (rd == -1)
        exit(99);

    return (*buff);
}

ssize_t _getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream)
{
    char *temp;
    const size_t n_alloc = 120;
    size_t n_read = 0;
    size_t n_realloc;
    int c;

    if (lineptr == NULL || n == NULL || stream == NULL)
        return (-1);

    if (*lineptr == NULL)
    {
        *lineptr = malloc(n_alloc);
        if (*lineptr == NULL)
            return (-1);
        *n = n_alloc;
    }
    while ((c = _getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (n_read >= *n)
        {
            n_realloc = *n + n_alloc;
            temp = realloc(*lineptr, n_realloc + 1);

            if (temp == NULL)
                return (-1);

            *lineptr = temp;
            *n = n_realloc;
        }
        n_read++;
        (*lineptr)[n_read - 1] = (char) c;

        if (c == '\n')
            break;

    }
    if (c == EOF)
        return (-1);
    (*lineptr)[n_read] = '\0';
    return ((ssize_t) n_read);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8202897/2970947

Comment: If `ptr` is a pointer, then `*ptr` dereferences that pointer, to get the object it points to. If `*ptr` is an array, then `(*ptr)[i]` accesses element with index `i` of that array.

Comment: `*ptr` always means exactly the same as `ptr[0]`. So `(*ptr)[i]` is exactly the same as `ptr[0][i]`.

Comment: So, does this mean that (*lineptr)[n_read] = '\0'; will null terminate the [n_read] array at its last position? @ElliottFrisch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char **lineptr` means `lineptr` contains the adress of a `char` pointer.

A pointer is a variable that contains an adress. So by writing `*lineptr`you're getting that adress.

In your case, `**lineptr` <=> `*(*lineptr)` <=> `(*lineptr)[0]`

Edit : btw I was not answering the question... the instruction `(*lineptr)[n_read] = '\0'` means you're ending your string (`'\0'` is EOF (End Of Line) character).

Comment: No. It means you are assigning zero. `ptr` may hava any type for example `uint64_t **` or `double **`. It does not have to be a string.

Comment: So, does this mean that ```(*lineptr)[n_read] = '\0';``` will null terminate the ```[n_read]``` array at its last position? @0___________

Comment: No, it will place zero at `n_read` char element of the pointer referenced by `lineptr`

Answer (score 1):

They look the same but are different.

The fist one:

```
int (*ptr)[something];
```

defines the pointer to `int` `something` elements array

The latter

```
(*ptr1)[something]   //witohut type in front of it.
```

means derefence pointer `ptr1` and then dereference the result of previous dereference with added `something`.

And it is an equivalent of

```
*((*ptr1) + something)
```

Comment: So, does this mean that ```(*lineptr)[n_read] = '\0';``` will null terminate the ```[n_read]``` array at its last position?