# syntax error before '[' token

Tags: c, struct, syntax-error, typedef

Here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
typedef struct std_thread
{
 char name[20];
 int hallno;
 int empid;
 char dept[5];
}std[5];

void *print(void *args)
{
 struct std_thread *data=(struct std_thread *)args;
 printf("My thread id is %ld\n",pthread_self());
 printf("Thread %d is executing\n",args);
 printf("Name\tHall No\tEmployee ID\tDepartment\n");
 printf("--------------------------------------------------------");
 printf("%s\t%d\t%d\t%s\n",data->name,data->hallno,data->empid,data->dept);
}

int main()
{
 pthread_t th[5];
 int empid=2020;
 int hall=1;
 char dept[2]="IT";
 char *names[]={"dinesh","vignesh","pradeep","prasath","mohan"};
 int t;
 int i;
 int status;
 for(i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
   std[i].name=names[i]; //Getting error from this line
   std[i].hallno=hall;   //Error at this line
   hall++;
   std[i].empid=empid;  //Error at this line
   empid++;
   std[i].dept=dept;     //Error at this line
   status=pthread_create(&th[i],NULL,print,(void *)&std[i]);
   if(status)
   {
    printf("Error creating threads\n");
    exit(0);
   }

 }
 pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

While compiling this code, I'm getting "syntax error before '[' token". What is the reason for this?

Comment: Your example contains too much code to demonstrate the problem, please shorten in the future (for instance why have the `print` function defined?)  Also be aware that `std` is used to indicate the standard namespace in C++.  So naming your variables or types `std` will make it very hard if you ever want to integrate your code into a C++ codebase...you should avoid that (as well as naming things `class`, etc.)

Comment: Ok, HostileFork. Thanks for your  advice. Hereafter I won't make mistakes like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This declaration does not do what you think it does:

```
typedef struct std_thread
{
  ...
}std[5];
```

This declares a `struct` named `std_thread`, and then it creates a `typedef` named `std` to mean "an array of 5 `struct std_thread` objects".

You probably wanted one of these two definitions, in order to declare a global object named `std` as an array of 5 `struct std_thread`'s:

```
typedef struct std_thread
{
  ...
} std_thread;
std_thread std[5];

// OR

struct std_thread
{
  ..
} std[5];
```

In the first case, we also create the `typedef` named `std_thread` as an alias for `struct std_thread`; in the second case, we do not.

Furthermore, as others have stated, you cannot copy character arrays by assignment.  You must copy them using a function such as [`strcpy(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) or [`strncpy(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy).  When using `strcpy`, you must ensure that the destination buffer is large enough to hold the desired string.  Also keep in mind that [`strncpy` does not necessarily null-terminate its destination string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453876/why-does-strncpy-not-null-terminate), so use it with caution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you mean to `typedef` up the top.

What you've written there makes `std` an equivalent **type** as five of the `struct`s in an array, but then you use `std` as though it is itself an array.

Remove the word `typedef` from line five and it should be closer to working.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are trying to copy a string using assignment:

   ```
   std[i].name=names[i];
   ```

   and

   ```
   std[i].dept=dept;
   ```

   that does not work. Use a `strcpy` or better `strncpy` instead.
2. You have a typo in:

   ```
   std[i].empid=empdid;  //Error at this line
   ```

   You don't have a var named `empdid`.

Answer (score 1):

Use string copy function instead of assigning char array.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
typedef struct std_thread
{
    char name[20];
    int  hallno;
    int  empid;
    char dept[5];
} std[5];
```

declares the type `std` to be an array of 5 `struct std_thread` structures.

This code:

```
int main()
{
[...]
    int i;
    int status;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std[i].name = names[i];
```

assumes that `std` is a variable with array or pointer type.

You need to remove the keyword `typedef` to make the code consistent with the use of the variable.

Then you can start running into problems with string assignments where you need to use string copy functions, etc.