# (C) How to use strncat() with **argv?

Tags: c, pointers, argv

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

   char file_extension[10];

   strncat(file_extension, argv[2][5], 6);
```

When I do this, I get "warning: passing arg 2 of 'strncat' makes pointer from integer without a cast'. Does does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: So C or C++? Remove the C++ tag if it's C.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve? What you currently have has at least two UBs inside and it also makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: I'm trying to extract the file extension from an argument. I left out most of the other code to make this simple. What is a "UB"?

Comment: @userXXX For that, why don't you use `char *extension = 1 + strchr(argv[1], '.');`?

Comment: @user1472747 UB is an acronym for 'undefined behavior'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems:

- `argv[2][5]` is a single character: the 6th character of the 3rd input argument, but the second argument of `strncat` takes a *pointer to a character* (i.e. a C string), not a single character
- `file_extension` is not null-terminated to begin with (it's uninitialized), so it's Undefined Behavior to call `strncat` on it
- The last argument to `strncat` is the maximum number of characters of the source string to concatenate, not the size of the output buffer -- it does not protect you from buffer overflows.
- If you actually meant to write `strncpy` instead of `strncat`, then you also need to be aware that [`strncpy` **does not necessarily null-terminate the output**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453876/why-does-strncpy-not-null-terminate)

There are are easy fixes to these problems, but the best fix for you depends on exactly what you're going to do: is the file extension read-only?  Are you constructing a new filename?  What's going to happen with it?

I *strongly* recommend you get a good book about C strings and C programming instead of trying to blindly write string code without having a solid understanding of what it's doing, especially with the high risk of buffer overflows and memory corruption when the code is not written correctly.

Comment: You are confusing `strncpy` with `strncat` in your second and third points.

Comment: Editing it to say `strncpy` doesn't help since the question uses `strncat`.

Comment: @interjay: Whoops sorry, I was a little confused there, it should be fixed now

Answer (score 3):

`argv[2]` is a `char *`, so that would make `argv[2][5]` a `char`

`strncat` accepts `char *` parameters only!

Comment: thank you! Then, do you know how to make a new string, say from argv[2][3] to argv[2][7]?

Comment: @user1472747 `memcpy()`. And don't forget the terminating `NUL`.

Comment: If you want to do strncat of file_extension to a substring of argv[2], you will do this:

Answer (score 2):

`argv[2][5]` is a char only.

Try with just `argv[2]`.

Answer (score 2):

So if I finally managed to comprehend correctly all your ambiguous comments: it seems that you want to copy a part of a string.

```
const char foo[] = "abcdefghijklm";
const size_t start = 3;
const size_t len = 5;

char the_copy[len + 1];
memcpy(the_copy, foo + start, len);
the_copy[len] = 0;
```

Comment: @user1472747 You're welcome. I'm not "eager". See, I was a beginner too, and it was not very long ago. Yet I didn't have to ask questions like this. Show some creativity! The documentation of the standard library functions is also helpful. And if you listen to one more advice: don't want to do everything the first day you start programming! It will take several months, years, etc. till you have the necessary experience for something complex.