# Why is this simple code not compiling?

Tags: c

I have problem to compile the following lines:

```
/*This code compiles with error*/
char HeLev1[6];
HeLev1[]="45.0";
/*but this is OK:*/
char HeLev1[6]="45.0";
```

Comment: What error message does your compiler give?

Comment: Arrays are not assignable. Apart from that, `HeLev1[]` isn't an expression.

Comment: And assignment statements cannot appear outside a function body.

Comment: To copy a string, you should use `strcpy()`, you can't do it with an assignment.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot assign values to an array. You need to assign values to array elements one-by-one (or, when dealing with strings, using `strcpy()`)

```
char HeLev1[6];
strcpy(HeLev1, "45.0");

char HeLev2[6];
HeLev2[0] = '4';
HeLev2[1] = '5';
HeLev2[2] = '.';
HeLev2[3] = '0';
HeLev2[4] = '\0'; /* properly "terminate" the string */
```

Note that in your code, the OK part, you have an *array initialization*, not assignment.

Also note that, in both cases above, the 6th element (`HeLev1[5]` or `HeLev2[5]`) has an undefined value (garbage).

Comment: Doesn't your first example miss the nul char too? OR is it implicit? I can't remember

Comment: You can always `memcpy()` arrays, no?

Comment: @0A0D: The nul char is implicit. You just need to make sure there is enough space in the array for all the characters **and** the nul char.

Comment: @millimoose: Yes, but don't do that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1454018/195488

Comment: @0A0D: I meant in the general case, for not-strings, as a contradiction to the "you need to assign values to array elements one-by-one" part. Assuming that you have an array with a known length etc.

Comment: @millimoose: yes, you can use `memcpy()` or `memmove()` which, just like `strcpy()`, are nothing but element-by-element copies in a loop :)

Comment: @pmg This doesn't seem to hold true for `glibc`. There's a whole bunch of architecture specific assembly in the source providing optimised implementations.

Comment: @millimoose: well sure, but how was I supposed to know? We are talking about char arrays here :)

Answer (score -1):

you can assign whole values to an array only while initialization. like these are correct forms,

```
char HeLev1[6]="45.0";
int array[3]={1,2,3};
char HeLev1[]="45.0";
int array[]={1,2,3};
```

but once you have skipped this part. you have to assign element by element. like,

```
    char HeLev2[6];
    HeLev2[0] = '4';
    HeLev2[1] = '5';
    HeLev2[2] = '.';
    HeLev2[3] = '0';
    HeLev2[4] = '\0'; /* properly "terminate" the string */
```

or you can use memcpy or strcpy.