# strncpy doesn't always null-terminate

Tags: c, strncpy

I am using the code below:

```
char filename[ 255 ];
strncpy( filename, getenv( "HOME" ), 235 );
strncat( filename, "/.config/stationlist.xml", 255 );
```

Get this message:

```
(warning) Dangerous usage of strncat - 3rd parameter is the maximum number of characters to append.
(error) Dangerous usage of 'filename' (strncpy doesn't always null-terminate it).
```

Comment: what is your actual question?

Comment: just curious, but which compiler gives those messages?

Comment: @andrewcooke Google says it is `cppcheck` static analyzer

Comment: Dagerous use of getenv(): it can return NULL, and result in dangerous use of str[n]cpy();

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does strncpy not null terminate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453876/why-does-strncpy-not-null-terminate)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I typically avoid using `str*cpy()` and `str*cat()`. You have to contend with boundary conditions, arcane API definitions, and unintended performance consequences.

You can use `snprintf()` instead. You only have to be contend with the size of the destination buffer. And, it is safer in that it will not overflow, and will always NUL terminate for you.

```
char filename[255];
const char *home = getenv("HOME");
if (home == 0) home = ".";
int r = snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "%s%s", home, "/.config/stationlist.xml");
if (r >= sizeof(filename)) {
    /* need a bigger filename buffer... */
} else if (r < 0) {
    /* handle error... */
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution but how can having to parse a format string ("%s%s") and a vararg be faster than just copying bytes over from A to B?

Comment: @Oliver: When I was talking about performance consequences, I was talking about code that repeatedly calls `str*cat()` in succession, rather than a single `snprintf()` call to do the same task. But you are correct, calling `snprintf()` too often is not a good idea in performance sensitive code paths. I don't see it being a problem for forming the path to a configuration file.

Answer (score 5):

You may overflow `filename` with your `strncat` call.

Use:

```
strncat(filename, "/.config/stationlist.xml",
        sizeof filename - strlen(filename) - 1);
```

Also be sure to null terminate your buffer after `strncpy` call:

```
strncpy( filename, getenv( "HOME" ), 235 );
filename[235] = '\0';
```

as `strncpy` does not null terminate its destination buffer if the length of the source is larger or equal than the maximum number of character to copy.

Comment: That last sentence needs to be printed in every page of documentation on this method.

Answer (score 3):

`man strncpy` has this to say:

```
Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes
of src, the string placed in dest will not be null terminated.
```

If it encounters the 0 byte in the source before it exhausts the maximum length, it will be copied. But if the maximum length is reached before the first 0 in the source, the destination will not be terminated. Best to make sure it is yourself after `strncpy()` returns...

Answer (score 2):

Both `strncpy()` and (even more so) `strncat()` have non-obvious behaviours and you would be best off not using either.

#### strncpy()

If your target string is, for sake of argument, 255 bytes long, `strncpy()` will always write to all 255 bytes.  If the source string is shorter than 255 bytes, it will zero pad the remainder.  If the source string is longer than 255 bytes, it will stop copying after 255 bytes, leaving the target without a null terminator.

#### strncat()

The size argument for most of the 'sized' functions (`strncpy()`, `memcpy()`, `memmove()`, etc) is the number of bytes in the target string (memory).  With `strncat()`, the size is the amount of space left after the end of the string that's already in the target.  Therefore, you can only safely use `strncat()` when you know both how big the target buffer is (`S`) and how long the target string currently is (`L`).  The safe parameter to `strncat()` is then `S-L` (we'll worry about whether there's an off-by-one some other time).  But given that you know `L`, there is no point in making `strncat()` skip the `L` characters; you could have passed `target+L` as the place to start, and simply copied the data.  And you could use `memmove()` or `memcpy()`, or you could use `strcpy()`, or even `strncpy()`.  If you don't know the length of the source string, you've got to be confident that it makes sense to truncate it.

#### Analysis of code in question

```
char filename[255];
strncpy(filename, getenv("HOME"), 235);
strncat(filename, "/.config/stationlist.xml", 255);
```

The first line is unexceptionable unless the size is deemed too small (or you run the program in a context where `$HOME` is not set), but that's out of scope for this question.  The call to `strncpy()` does not use `sizeof(filename)` for the size, but rather an arbitrarily small number.  It isn't the end of the world, but there's no guarantee that the last 20 bytes of the variable are zero bytes (or even that any of them is a zero byte), in general.  Under some circumstances (`filename` is a global variable, previously unused) the zeros might be guaranteed.

The `strncat()` call tries to append 24 characters to the end of the string in `filename` that might already be 232-234 bytes long, or that might be arbitrarily longer than 235 bytes.  Either way, that is a guaranteed buffer overflow.  The usage of `strncat()` also falls directly into the trap about its size.  You've said that it is OK to add up to 255 characters beyond the end of what's already in `filename`, which is blatantly wrong (unless the string from `getenv("HOME")` happens to be empty).

Safer code:

```
char filename[255];
static const char config_file[] = "/.config/stationlist.xml";
const char *home = getenv("HOME");
size_t len = strlen(home);
if (len > sizeof(filename) - sizeof(config_file))
    ...error file name will be too long...
else
{
    memmove(filename, home, len);
    memmove(filename+len, config_file, sizeof(config_file));
}
```

There will be those who insist that '`memcpy()` is safe because the strings cannot overlap', and at one level they're correct, but overlap should be a non-issue and with `memmove()`, it is a non-issue.  So, I use `memmove()` all the time...but I've not done the timing measurements to see how big of a problem it is, if it is a problem at all.  Maybe the other people have done the measurements.

#### Summary

1. Don't use `strncat()`.
2. Use `strncpy()` cautiously (noting its behaviour on very big buffers!).
3. Plan to use `memmove()` or `memcpy()` instead; if you can do the copy safely, you know the sizes necessary to make this sensible.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your strncpy does not necessarily null-terminate filename. In fact, if getenv("HOME") is longer than 235 characters and getenv("HOME")[234] is not a 0, it won't. 
2) Your strncat() may attempt to extend filename beyond 255 characters, because, as it says,

```
3rd parameter is the maximum number of characters to append.
```

(not the total allowed length of dst)

Comment: If filename is an automatic variable it will not be initialised (or zeroed-out as you call it)

Answer (score 0):

`strncpy(Copied_to,Copied_from,sizeof_input)` outputs garbage values after the character array (not used for string type). To solve it output using a for loop traversing the character array rather than simply using `cout<<var;`

```
for(i=0;i<size;i++){cout<<var[i]}
```

I couldn't find a work around for traversal on a windows system using minGW compiler.
Null termination does not solve the problem. Online compilers works just fine.