# strdup and free usage

Tags: c++, c, free, strdup

I'm trying this code:

```
imei=Found_imei(pClient->GetBuffer());
printf("6. CODICE IMEI %s \n",imei); 
pClient->SetImei(imei);
printf("6.1 CODICE IMEI %s \n",pClient->GetImei());
free(imei); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
printf("6.2 CODICE IMEI %s \n",pClient->GetImei());
```

where

```
char *Found_imei(char *string) 
{
char *start;
char *end;
char str[40];
int l;

start=strstr(string,"imei:");

strstr(start,",");

l=end-start-5;
strncpy(str,start+5,l);
str[l]='\0';
return strdup(str); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 
}
```

After free command, an error occured in printf.

I'm doing some error in using strdup and free?

Thanks

Comment: Please post `SetImei` and `GetImei`, the problem is 99% caused by something in there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess htat `GetImei` and `SetImei` are thin wrappers over a field of type `char*`.  If that is the case then the `free` call is freeing the memory which backs the `char*` value.  Hence the call to `GetImei` after the free is accessing freed memory and hence has undefined behavior

Answer (score 1):

`char *end;` is used `l=end-start-5;` before it is initialized.

Thus

```
l=end-start-5;
strncpy(str,start+5,l); // god knows how far this goes. more than 40 easy
str[l]='\0'; // and here
return strdup(str); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

str can be overwritten ( out of bounds ), after that all bets are off.

Answer (score 1):

Several obvious problems I see:

1. The return value of `strstr(start,",");` is ignored, making that function call useless
2. `end` is never initialized inside of the `Found_imei` function, so the pointer arithmetic `l=end-start-5;` results in Undefined Behavior
3. [`strncpy` doesn't always null-terminate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096146/strncpy-doesnt-always-null-terminate) its output.  That can easily lead to walking off the end of a string and into Undefined Behavior.
4. You're passing in `l` as the length parameter to `strncpy` when you should actually be passing the buffer size minus 1.  If `l` is 40 or more, you're going to be copying too many characters into `str` and smash your stack.

I suspect that problems 1 and 2 are the result of a failure to copy+paste your exact code, since it looks like you intended to write `end = strstr(start,",");`, but I can't be sure.  Nevertheless, problems 3 and 4 are still serious problems.