# Passing structs holding static arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I was wondering if it was okay to pass around/return structs holding statically allocated arrays in C++. For example:

```
typedef struct t{
    char name[32];
    int id;
}t;

t foo(char name[]){
    t my_t = {name, 0};
    return my_t;
}

int main(){
    t main_t = foo("a struct");
    printf("%s", main_t.name); //is this safe to access? 
    return 0;
}
```

When it returns the struct by value, I guess it doesn't copy the array name, only the pointer to it.

Edit: Just to clear up some things. I do know that `char *var` is equal to `char var[]` in function arguments. I wrote this code up really quickly without even testing it. I know it is definitely not the best code in the world and I wouldn't advice anybody to use it in real life. 
Ideally I would allocate the struct dynamically and pass around a pointer, however, I am teaching a person to program in C/C++. It is for a national exam which doesn't require a person to know dynamic allocation or pointers for that matter, that is why `*` are not really used at all.

The question is really about whether it is okay to return a struct holding a statically allocated array.

Shall we use this piece of code instead:

```
#include <iostream>

struct t{
    char name[32];
    int id;
};

t foo(int id){
    t my_t;
    my_t.id = id;
    for(char i = 0; i < 31; i++){
        my_t.name[i] = 'a';
    }
    my_t.name[31] = '\0';
    return my_t;
}

int main(){
    t main_t = foo(0);
    std::cout << main_t.name; //is this safe to access? 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't compile since you're trying to assign a `char*` to a `char[]` here `t my_t = {name, 0}`.

Comment: Mixing up C and C++ is not a good idea in most cases. For example, a C++ answer may define copy constructor and copy assignment, whereas a C answer may introduce a clone method.

Comment: `foo(char name[])` is useless. Basically it is a `foo(char*)` without any size

Comment: @MrSpreadsheet Which language c or c++?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done.

But it shouldn't be done: alternatives are `std::string` and `std::array`.  You get your copy, allocation, deallocation etc... for free!

```
struct t {
    std::string name;
    int id;
    std::array<int, 10> integers;
};

...

t main_t = {"a struct"};
main_t.integers[5] = 5;
t copy = main_t;
assert( copy.name == "a struct" );
assert( copy.id == 0 );
assert( copy.integers[5] == 5 );
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no `static` array in your code.
2. When you return a `t` instance by value, it **will** copy the contents of the array.
3. The problem is with how you're initializing the `t` instance, **not** with how you're returning it.

---

Change this:

```
t my_t = {name,0};
```

To this:

```
t my_t = {0};
strncpy(my_t.name,name,sizeof(my_t.name)-1);
```

Or to this, if you want to avoid the use of library functions:

```
int i;
t my_t;
for (i=0; i<sizeof(my_t.name)-1 && name[i]!=0; i++)
    my_t.name[i] = name[i];
my_t.name[i] = 0;
my_t.id = 0;
```

Comment: [Better use `strncat`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453876/why-does-strncpy-not-null-terminate)

Comment: Click on the link ;) If the source string is longer than the destination can hold, it will not be null terminated. `strncpy` doesn't copy a string, since the result is not necessarily a "string" (null terminated).

Comment: @leemes: That's what the `t my_t = {0}` is for.

Comment: Now that you have `sizeof(...)-1` it seems to be safe, but I remember you didn't have that before.

Comment: @leemes: Yeah, I added it immediately after committing the initial answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've an error in your program; you're trying to copy a pointer to an array, instead you should copy the contents pointed to by the pointer into the array. It should be like this

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

struct t
{
    char name[32];
    int id;
};

t foo(const char *name)
{
    t my_t = {};
    const size_t len = std::strlen(name);
    const size_t max_len = sizeof(t::name) / sizeof(t::name[0]) - 1u;
    std::copy(name, name + std::min(len, max_len), my_t.name);
    return my_t;
}

int main()
{
    t main_t = foo("a struct");
    printf("%s", main_t.name);
}
```

As for your question

> I was wondering if it was okay to pass around/return structs holding static arrays in C++

Yes, it's ok, the whole struct will get copied (or moved, depending on the type) to the variable at the calling end.

Comment: And, you will know the array length at compile-time, so you cannot pass to small buffers.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to pass around structs that contain arrays. However, this line doesn't do what you think it does:

```
t my_t = {name, 0};
```

Using designated initializer syntax, it would be equivalent to:

```
t my_t = {  .name[0] = name;  .name[1] = 0; };
```

The first member of `t` is an array with 32 elements, so the first 32 initializers are applied to those 32 `char`s. Unless you use some more braces, but you still need one initializer per element, there's no magic way to get a `strcpy` out of brace-enclosed initializers.

You should get a compiler error about initializing a `char` with a pointer.

Comment: So basically, when I define the size of an array in a struct at the compile time, does the memory get allocated inside the struct itself, instead of a pointer? And then when I return it, the whole of the array gets copied? That was the question which was bugging me.
I mean, struct access works with offsets, so it would be logical.