# cppcheck - terminateStrncpy

Tags: c++, static-code-analysis, strncpy, cppcheck

New to cppcheck. Couldn't figure out how to solve this issue (cppcheck warning). any help would be appreciated.

```
 if (!call_initialized)
 { char id1[16];
   char id1[16];
   char* dummy_char_ptr = inet_ntoa(*((in_addr*)&source_ip));
   std::strncpy(id1, dummy_char_ptr, 16);
   dummy_char_ptr=inet_ntoa(*((in_addr*)&destination_ip));
   std::strncpy(id2, dummy_char_ptr, 16);
   dummy_char_ptr=NULL;
   std::cerr << id1 << " -----> " << id2 << std::endl;
   return 0;
   }
```

error(warning) - The buffer 'id2' may not be zero-terminated after the call to strncpy().

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453876/why-does-strncpy-not-null-terminate

Comment: http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `strncpy` (unless you really know what you're doing).

`strncpy(dst, src, n)` always writes exactly `n` bytes. If `src` does not have a `NUL` byte in its first `n` bytes, no `NUL` byte will be written to `dst`, so you can turn a valid NUL-terminated string into an unterminated string (which is why you get the warning). If `src` is shorter than `n` bytes, `strncpy` will add `NUL` bytes to the end, which is usually unnecessary.

Personally, I would use `strdup` (and remember to `free` the resulting copy when I'm done with it), because it is easier. `strdup` is a Posix extension to standard C library, but it's easy to write if you need it, and it exists on most platforms (as `_strdup` on Windows, iirc). Alternatively, you could strncpy one fewer byte than the size of your buffer, and then add a NUL at the end, or you could just check the length of the source string with `strlen` and fail if it is too long.