# Random letters at the end of my string?

Tags: c, arrays, string, projects

```
void split(char array[]) {
    int length, length2, half; 
    char first_half[BUF], sec_half[BUF];

    length = strlen(array);
    length2 = length / 2;
    length -= length2;

    strncpy(first_half, array, length - 1);
    strncpy(sec_half, (array + length), length2 - 1);

    printf("%s\n", first_half);
    printf("%s\n", sec_half);
}
```

**If input is "People", it outputs:**
**Pe0z
  plcy etc... Just wondering what's the problem here.**

My question is not the same as the question mentioned. I am not trying to insert a word in the middle of another word, I am trying to split a word in half and put the two halves in two strings.

Comment: C-String must end with NUL.

Comment: I thought it automatically filled the end of the string with null characters so I dont understand what to do to fix the problem

Comment: [strncpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) fills NUL when the actual string is short.

Comment: It will null terminate if there's room, but if your string is longer than the size you give for the buffer it will not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does strncpy not null terminate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453876/why-does-strncpy-not-null-terminate)

Comment: `strncpy` is easy to misuse. Might as well use `memcpy` and manually add the NUL terminator.

Comment: BUF = 255. When i look at this first_half would only have 3 characters in it. 3 is less than 255. Just wanted to explain my thinking so you guys would understand how I am confused.

Comment: If there's no NUL within the first "length" bytes of the source the destination won't be NUL terminated.

Comment: Okay can someone help me fix the problem. I understand it's not null terminating.

Comment: Perhaps `memcpy` the the left half of the source and add your own NUL. `strcpy` the right half, it will correctly terminate the destination.

Comment: fix like [this](http://ideone.com/Bws7In)

Comment: BLUEPIXY thank you man.

Answer (score 2):

OP's trouble is that `first_half[BUF], sec_half[BUF]` are not certainly null character terminated - a short coming of `strncpy()`.

```
strncpy( first_half, array, length);
// printf( "%s\n", first_half );
// alternative limited width print, even if `first_half` lacks a null character.
printf( "%.*s\n", length, first_half );
```

---

> trying to split a <strike>word</strike>string in half and put the two halves in two strings.

Below is a variable length array (VLA) approach.

I recommend `memcpy()` as that is often fastest for long strings and lest error prone than `strncpy()`  [@Blastfurnace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046917/random-letters-at-the-end-of-my-string/45048089?noredirect=1#comment77068114_45046917).  [YMMV](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/YMMV).

```
void split(const char array[]) {
  size_t a_length = strlen(array);
  size_t l_length = a_length / 2;
  size_t r_length = a_length - l_length;
  char l_half[l_length + 1], r_half[r_length + 1];  // + 1 for null character

  memcpy(l_half, array, l_length);
  l_half[l_length] = '\0';
  memcpy(r_half, array + l_length, r_length + 1); // +1 for null character

  printf("<%s>\n", l_half);
  printf("<%s>\n", r_half);
}
```

`size_t`, an *unsigned type*, is the right sized integer type to use for array indexing.  `int` maybe insufficient.  Note that `strlen()` returns type `size_t`.

---

If all that is wanted is to print the 2 halves, not much code needed:

```
void split_print(const char array[]) {
  int half = strlen(array) / 2;
  printf("%.*s\n", half, array);
  printf("%s\n", array + half);
}
```

Comment: Looks like great minds were thinking alike and hit on the VLA as an attractive alternative. Good to be with you.

Comment: @chux Small typo: `left_half[l_length] = '\0';` should be `l_half[l_length] = '\0';`

Comment: @sg7 Yes.  Code amended.

Answer (score 1):

Since I see that there is a concern about performance, I'd say get rid of **strncpy** altogether.

```
fist_half[l_length] = '\0';
while(l_length--)
  first_half[l_length] = array[l_length];
```

The same method can be applied to the right side with some index modification.
This way you can get rid of overhead and *HEADACES* of **strncpy**.

If you use pointers the code can be even further simplified.

Comment: Not a bad approach, but you can simply use `while (l_length--)` (it will test false when it hits `0` anyway `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You are absolutely  right. I edit my code snippet accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

One other issue not yet considered is "*How do I handle words with an odd number of characters?*". It's easy to split `1234` into `12` and `34`, but how do you split `123`? You must decide how to test for odd/even and decide which half gets the extra character (generally the first half, but it's up to you). You should also consider splitting strings of any size (and validate against processing a NULL pointer or empty-string passed to your function).

To handle checking odd/even length, all you need to do is check the 1st-bit of length on little-endian systems, or for complete portability just use *modulo* `2`. If the 1st-bit (on little-endian) or the result of `len % 2` is `0` it's even, otherwise the length is odd. (if odd, just add `+1` character to the first half).

If your compiler supports *Variable Length Array* C99 extensions, the problem becomes simply a matter of declaring the two VLAs and letting the compiler handle the work, e.g.

```
void split_vla (char *s)
{
    if (!s || !*s) {  /* validate parameter not NULL or empty-string */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: s NULL or empty-string.\n");
        return;
    }

    size_t l = strlen (s), 
        n = (l % 2 == 0) ? l / 2 : l / 2 + 1;
    char s1[n + 1], s2[n + 1];  /* declare VLAs */

    memcpy (s1, s, n);          /* memcpy chars to each half */
    memcpy (s2, s + n, l - n);

    s1[n] = 0;                  /* affirmatively nul-terminate */
    s2[l - n] = 0;

    printf ("s  : %s\ns1 : %s\ns2 : %s\n", s, s1, s2);
}
```

If it doesn't, you can always *dynamically allocate* storage for each of the halfs (and if you choose `calloc` over `malloc`, then your storage is initialized to all zeros (providing a *nul-byte* at the end of each half), e.g.

```
void split_dyn (char *s)
{
    if (!s || !*s) {  /* validate parameter not NULL or empty-string */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: s NULL or empty-string.\n");
        return;
    }

    size_t l = strlen (s),
        n = (l % 2 == 0) ? l / 2 : l / 2 + 1;
    char *s1, *s2;

    /* allocate storage for s1 & s2 and validate allocation */
    if (!(s1 = calloc (n + 1, 1)) || !(s2 = calloc (n + 1, 1))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memcpy (s1, s, n);          /* memcpy chars to each half */
    memcpy (s2, s + n, l - n);

    printf ("s  : %s\ns1 : %s\ns2 : %s\n", s, s1, s2);

    free (s1);    /* don't forget to free the memory you allocate */
    free (s2);
}
```

Either way is fine depending on what your compiler supports. You are free to use `malloc` and affirmatively *nul-terminate* as was done in the VLA example. Also be aware that `alloca` gives similar functionality to what you get with VLAs, but provides a bit more flexibility in the scope for your arrays (not relevant here since the VLAs are declared with function scope but be aware of the additional method).  Give both examples a try and let me know if you have further questions.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/str_split_half 123456789
s  : 123456789
s1 : 12345
s2 : 6789

$ ./bin/str_split_half 1234567890
s  : 1234567890
s1 : 12345
s2 : 67890

$ ./bin/str_split_half 1
s  : 1
s1 : 1
s2 :
```

Comment: Unclear why `!*s` test needed: `split_vla ("")` seems like an OK call.  `n = (l % 2 == 0) ? l / 2 : l / 2 + 1;` can be simplified to `n = (l + 1)/2;` in this case. `s2[n + 1]` is OK yet 1 larger than needed with odd `l`.  Still a useful post.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough if you initialize the buffers with 0 as shown in `split1(...)`

```
char first_half[BUF] = {0}; // whole buffer is full of zeroes
char sec_half[BUF] = {0};
```

Then termination will be automatic.

The uninitialized buffer contains random characters.
If buffers are not zeroed the termination is needed as shown in `split2(...)`

The solutions are as close as possible to the original code. They work for even, odd and empty strings.

Please note the symmetry of the solutions with `memcpy` and `strncpy`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF 255

void split1(char array[], int bUseMemcpy)
{
    /* use zeroed buffers to automatically terminated the copied strings */
    int length, length2; 
    char first_half[BUF] = {0};
    char sec_half[BUF] = {0};

    length = strlen( array );
    length2 = length / 2;
    length -= length2;

    if(bUseMemcpy)
        memcpy(  first_half, array, length); 
    else    
        strncpy( first_half, array, length); 

    if(bUseMemcpy)   
        memcpy(  sec_half, (array + length), length2);
    else    
        strncpy( sec_half, (array + length), length2);

    printf( "<%s>\n", first_half );
    printf( "<%s>\n", sec_half );
}

void split2(char array[], int bUseMemcpy)
{
    /* Do not initialize the buffers
     Use 0 to terminate the buffers after the copy */
    int length, length2;
    char first_half[BUF];
    char sec_half[BUF];  

    length = strlen(array);
    length2 = length / 2;
    length -= length2;

    if(bUseMemcpy)
        memcpy(  first_half, array, length); 
    else    
        strncpy( first_half, array, length);

    first_half[length]=0; /*zero termination needed, since buffers are not initialized to 0*/

    if(bUseMemcpy)   
        memcpy(  sec_half, (array + length), length2);
    else    
        strncpy( sec_half, (array + length), length2);

    sec_half[length2]=0; // zero termination

    printf( "<%s>\n", first_half );
    printf( "<%s>\n", sec_half );
  }

int main(void) {
    split1("123456789",0);
    split1("",1);

    split2("people",0);
    split2("1",1);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
<12345>
<6789>
<>
<>
<peo>
<ple>
<1>
<>
```

Comment: My issue with this is zeroing the entire buffer may be more work than necessary and if you reuse the buffer you can have incorrectly terminated strings from `strncpy` again.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I agree:  _`strncpy` is easy to misuse. Might as well use memcpy and manually add the NUL terminator_. In the example above the buffer is not reused though.

Comment: What happens with `"123456789"` or `"apple"`?

Comment: @David C. Rankin All cases are covered! The solutions work for even, odd and empty strings. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to output the string split on 2 separate lines: use `printf` with the `%.*s` conversion format. It prints a initial portion of the string argument:

```
void split(const char *array) {
    int half = strlen(array) / 2;
    printf("%.*s\n%s\n", half, array, array + half);
}
```