# What is the advantage of using `strncpy` over `snprintf`?

Tags: c

I just realized that I am in the habit of using `snprintf` for taking slices of strings, which now seems unconventional to me for several reasons (chiefly, the need to `#include <stdio.h>`). But after looking at `strncpy` more closely, I'm struggling to see why anyone would prefer it over `snprintf`.

To be clear, I'm comparing `strncpy(dest, src, count)` with `snprintf(dest, count + 1, "%s", src)`. `snprintf(dest, count + 1, src)` obviously causes problems whenever `src` contains `'%'`.

What stood out to me most was how much more `snprintf` *acts* like an `str`- function than `strncpy`, which by comparison feels more like a `mem`- function to me.

- If `strncpy` reaches the end of `src` before it copies `count` characters, it will write `count - strlen(src)` null characters *in addition to* the terminating null character copied from `src`.

  - This practice seems unnecessarily wasteful: functions expecting null-terminated strings (virtually every string function in C, for better or worse) would encounter the terminating null character and halt. Only `mem`- functions would even notice the additional characters, but I can't imagine the difference would ever be particularly useful. Also, if you're actually dealing with byte arrays, why are you using string functions?
  - From what I can tell, this is by-and-large *not* how C tends to deal with either arrays or strings. For example, `char foo[6] = "hi";` doesn't fill the remaining 3 bytes with null characters! Furthermore, in my experience, arrays are typically pre-initialized in this manner using... you guessed it, `memset`. A `mem`- function.
- If `strncpy` copies `count` characters before it reaches the end of `src`, *the resulting character array won't be null-terminated*. That's right, the *string copying* function sometimes *doesn't produce a valid string*. What?
- `strncpy`'s `count` argument doesn't include the terminating null character. This makes memory allocation a bit awkward since the character array must be allocated with at least `count + 1` bytes in order to store `count` characters as a proper null-terminated string. Even worse, the last character in the array still needs to be set to the null character, which you can only do with `strncpy` if you *know* that `strlen(src) == count + 1`.

Compare all of this to `snprintf`:

- `snprintf` copies at most `count - 1` characters and a null character, meaning you need an array of `count` elements to store it all. Sweet!
- If `snprintf` reaches the end of `src` before it copies `count - 1` characters, it just adds a terminating null character to `dest` and halts - no questions asked.
- If `snprintf` copies `count - 1` characters before it reaches the end of `src`, it still adds a terminating null character to the end of `dest`.

Why on earth is `strncpy` this way?

Comment: `strncpy` is probably faster (`sprintf` has to interpret the format string) and some implementations do no support the `printf` function family.

Comment: Read this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453876/why-does-strncpy-not-null-terminate. Basically `strncpy` is more or less useless.

Comment: If you are using the `n` part to guard agaisnt buffer overflow, then the code is broken anyway: you'll truncate necessary data. Also `sprintf` is guaranteed to NUL-terminate the output array while `strncpy` is not.

Comment: Nothing wrong with either one, though the `sprintf/snprintf` functions were intended to handle a variadic number of arguments providing data for the conversions within your format-string. If you have no need for conversions and are simply writing a text string, then `strcpy/strncpy` are the tools for the job.

Comment: On systems with limited resources you'll prefer `strncpy()` because it is so much smaller than `snprintf()`.

Comment: "For example, char foo[6] = "hi"; doesn't fill the remaining 3 bytes..." That is wrong. They will be initialized.

Comment: "strncpy's count argument doesn't include the terminating null character" It does. As the standard says: "The strncpy function copies not more than n characters (characters **that follow** a null character are not copied)  ... " So the null character is included.

Comment: @4386427 *It does.*  No, it does not.  [Footnote 308](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note308): "Thus, if there is no null character in the first n characters of the array pointed to by s2, the result will not be null-terminated."  Not the use of terms such as `n-1` for [functions such as `snprintf()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.5p2): "... output characters beyond the n-1st are discarded..."  That all-important `n-1`-type term is lacking in `strncpy()` - it does not *include* any terminator, it *pads* the target buffer with zero bytes only if necessary.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Different thing. It still copy `count` characters. That's the whole point of the function. Always write `count` characters to the destination

Comment: @Jabberwocky IMO it's worse than useless.  It's pernicious.  It's name belies its misleading semantics.  It's name implies it copies the more-or-less standard "at most `n-1` bytes" into the target buffer then "add a null terminator", to use the C standard's words.  But that's not what it does...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the advantage of using `strncpy` over `snprintf`?

Virtually none.  The *only* advantage of `strncpy` (over anything) is if you want to create what the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/lib/strncpy.html) calls a "now-obsolete data structure, the fixed-length, not-necessarily-`\0`-terminated 'string.'"

If your goal is to copy the string `src` to the destination `dst`, as a proper (but possibly truncated) string, and without overflowing `dst`'s size `dstsize`, then

```
snprintf(dst, dstsize, "%s", src);
```

is actually a pretty good way to do it.  (Not the only way, and not a bad way, but perhaps overkill.)

On the other hand, `strncpy(dst, src, dstsize)`, is no solution to this problem at all.

Other possible solutions to this problem are

```
*dst = '\0'; strncat(dst, src, dstsize);

strlcpy(dst, src, dstsize);

strcpy_s(dst, dstsize, src);
```

> Why on earth is `strncpy` this way?

In the early days of C and Unix, it was somewhat common to use short, fixed-length pseudo-strings which were *not* necessarily null-terminated, but which were padded out to their "full length" with extra `\0`'s if necessary.  This meant that you could efficiently compare them using the equivalent of `memcmp`; you didn't have to check for `\0` at all.  See also the [footnote](http://c-faq.com/lib/strncpyexamp.html) to the aforementioned C FAQ list entry.

`strncpy` is pretty much obsolete today; many programmers recommend avoiding it entirely.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the advantage of using `strncpy` over `snprintf`?

Well, it doesn't really make sense to compare two functions that are really intended to do different things.

`strncpy` is designed to write **exactly** `n` characters to `dst`. Some or all (but at least 1) of these `n` characters may be copied from the string `src` and the remaining characters (if any) will be null characters. Unfortunately many C programmers think that `strncpy` is a "safe" version of `strcpy` but it's not and it's not what was intended. The name `strncpy` is probably what is misleading.

`snprintf` is designed for a completely different task, i.e. formatted printing to a string.

Special use cases of `sprintf` like `sprintf(dst, n, "%s", src)` may seem equivalent to `strncpy(dst, src, n)` because the result `dst` when viewed as a "traditional C style" string looks the same. But it's not truely identical calls. They do different things to generate the result `dst` and `dst` may be different when looking at all array elements (see example in the end of this answer).

> Why on earth is strncpy this way?

`strncpy` is handy when working with strings stored in fixed size arrays where no termination character is used and null padding is used for strings shorter than the array size.

*Example of `snprintf` appearing to do the same as `strncpy` while it's not*

```
int main ()
{
    char src[] = "Hi";
    char dst[6];
    strcpy(dst, "Hello");
    puts(dst);
    strncpy(dst, src, 6);
    puts(dst);
    puts("------------------");
    strcpy(dst, "Hello");
    puts(dst);
    snprintf(dst, 6, "%s", src);
    puts(dst);    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Hello
Hi
------------------
Hello
Hi
```

From the output it seems that the `strncpy` call and the `snprintf` call did the same, i.e. changed `dst` from "Hello" to "Hi".

However, a closer look at `dst` - like

```
void pp(const char* p)
{
    for (int i=0; i < 6; ++i) printf("%02X ", p[i]);
    puts("");
}

int main ()
{
    char src[] = "Hi";
    char dst[6];
    strcpy(dst, "Hello");
    puts(dst);
    strncpy(dst, src, 6);
    puts(dst);
    pp(dst);
    puts("------------------");
    strcpy(dst, "Hello");
    puts(dst);
    snprintf(dst, 6, "%s", src);
    puts(dst);    
    pp(dst);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Hello
Hi
48 69 00 00 00 00 
------------------
Hello
Hi
48 69 00 6C 6F 00
```

shows that the two calls actually resulted in different `dst` values.

Comment: Your example at the end still seems superficial to me. The definition of a "string" in C is *strictly* a null-terminated sequence of `char`s. Under this pretense, `48 69 00 00 00 00` and `48 69 00 6C 6F 00` should be considered equal (as is demonstrated by `strcmp`). The only time they should be considered distinct is with working with `void` arrays, a task that is restricted to `mem-` functions. `strncpy` therefore performs unnecessary operations for working with strings that technically impede performance (although not meaningfully in most cases).

Comment: @QuaternionsRock The whole point is that `strncpy` wasn't design to generate the atandard C-style string.