# Unexpected behavior when printing 4-byte integer byte by byte

Tags: c, ip-address, endianness, scanf

I have this sample code for converting 32 bit integers to ip addresses.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 unsigned int c ;
 unsigned char* cptr  = (unsigned char*)&c ;
 while(1)
 {
  scanf("%d",&c) ;
  printf("Integer value: %u\n",c);
  printf("%u.%u.%u.%u \n",*cptr, *(cptr+1), *(cptr+2), *(cptr+3) );
 }
}
```

This code gives incorrect output for input `2249459722` .
But when i replace

```
scanf("%d",&c) ;
```

by

```
scanf("%u",&c) ;
```

The output comes out to be correct.

**P.S** : I know about `inet_ntop` and `inet_pton`.
 I expect answers other than suggesting those.

Comment: What result did you get?  What result did you expect?

Comment: Rotten title. It doesn't tell the reader *anything* about the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: `2249459722` is not required to fit in an `int` or an `unsigned int` for that matter.  Use `unsigned long`, or if you have it available, `uint32_t`.  The format for `scanf()` becomes `"%lu"`/`"%" SCNu32` in that case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are coding '[sinfully](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071626751)' (making a number of mistakes which will hurt you sooner or later - mostly sooner).   First off, you are assuming that the integer is of the correct endian-ness. On some machines, you will be wrong - either on Intel machines or on PowerPC or SPARC machines.

In general, you should show the actual results you get rather than just saying that you get the wrong result; you should also show the expected result.  That helps people debug your expectations.

---

Here's my modified version of your code - instead of requesting input, it simply assumes the value you specified.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int c = 2249459722;
    unsigned char* cptr  = (unsigned char*)&c;
    printf("Integer value:  %10u\n", c);
    printf("Integer value:  0x%08X\n", c);
    printf("Dotted decimal: %u.%u.%u.%u \n", *cptr, *(cptr+1), *(cptr+2), *(cptr+3));
    return(0);
}
```

When compiled on my Mac (Intel, little-endian), the output is:

```
Integer value:  2249459722
Integer value:  0x8614080A
Dotted decimal: 10.8.20.134
```

When compiled on my Sun (SPARC, big-endian), the output is:

```
Integer value:  2249459722
Integer value:  0x8614080A
Dotted decimal: 134.20.8.10
```

(Using GCC 4.4.2 on the SPARC, I get a warning:

```
xx.c:4: warning: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90
```

Using GCC 4.2.1 on Mac - with lots of warnings enabled (`gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Werror`) - I don't get that warning, which is interesting.)  I can remove that by adding a `U` suffix to the integer constant.

---

Another way of looking at the problems is illustrated with the following code and the extremely fussy compiler settings shown above:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void print_value(unsigned int c)
{
    unsigned char* cptr  = (unsigned char*)&c;
    printf("Integer value:  %10u\n", c);
    printf("Integer value:  0x%08X\n", c);
    printf("Dotted decimal: %u.%u.%u.%u \n", *cptr, *(cptr+1), *(cptr+2), *(cptr+3));
}

int main(void)
{
    const char str[] = "2249459722";
    unsigned int c = 2249459722;

    printf("Direct operations:\n");
    print_value(c);

    printf("Indirect operations:\n");
    if (sscanf("2249559722", "%d", &c) != 0)
        printf("Conversion failed for %s\n", str);
    else
        print_value(c);
    return(0);
}
```

This fails to compile (because of the `-Werror` setting) with the message:

```
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
xx.c: In function ‘main’:
xx.c:20: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘unsigned int *’
```

Remove the `-Werror` setting and it compiles, but then shows the next problem that you have - the one of not checking for error indications from functions that can fail:

```
Direct operations:
Integer value:  2249459722
Integer value:  0x8614080A
Dotted decimal: 10.8.20.134 
Indirect operations:
Conversion failed for 2249459722
```

Basically, the `sscanf()` function reports that it failed to convert the string to a signed integer (because the value is too large to fit - see the warning from GCC 4.4.2), but your code was not checking for the error return from `sscanf()`, so you were using whatever value happened to be left in `c` at the time.

So, there are multiple problems with your code:

- It assumes a particular architecture (little-endian rather than recognizing that big-endian also exists).
- It doesn't compile cleanly when using a compiler with lots of warnings enabled - for good reason.
- It doesn't check that functions that can fail actually succeeded.

---

#### Alok's Comment

Yes, the test on `sscanf()` is wrong.  That's why you have code reviews, and also why it helps to post the code you are testing.

I'm now a bit puzzled - getting consistent behaviour that I can't immediately explain.  With the obvious revision (testing on MacOS X 10.6.2, GCC 4.2.1, 32-bit and 64-bit compilations), I get one not very sane answer.  When I rewrite more modularly, I get a sane answer.

```
+ cat yy.c
#include <stdio.h>

static void print_value(unsigned int c)
{
    unsigned char* cptr  = (unsigned char*)&c;
    printf("Integer value:  %10u\n", c);
    printf("Integer value:  0x%08X\n", c);
    printf("Dotted decimal: %u.%u.%u.%u \n", *cptr, *(cptr+1), *(cptr+2), *(cptr+3));
}

int main(void)
{
    const char str[] = "2249459722";
    unsigned int c = 2249459722;

    printf("Direct operations:\n");
    print_value(c);

    printf("Indirect operations:\n");
    if (sscanf("2249559722", "%d", &c) != 1)
        printf("Conversion failed for %s\n", str);
    else
        print_value(c);
    return(0);
}


+ gcc -o yy.32 -m32 -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes yy.c
yy.c: In function ‘main’:
yy.c:20: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘unsigned int *’


+ ./yy.32
Direct operations:
Integer value:  2249459722
Integer value:  0x8614080A
Dotted decimal: 10.8.20.134 
Indirect operations:
Integer value:  2249559722
Integer value:  0x86158EAA
Dotted decimal: 170.142.21.134
```

I do not have a good explanation for the value 170.142.21.134; but it is consistent on my machine, at the moment.

```
+ gcc -o yy.64 -m64 -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes yy.c
yy.c: In function ‘main’:
yy.c:20: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘unsigned int *’


+ ./yy.64
Direct operations:
Integer value:  2249459722
Integer value:  0x8614080A
Dotted decimal: 10.8.20.134 
Indirect operations:
Integer value:  2249559722
Integer value:  0x86158EAA
Dotted decimal: 170.142.21.134
```

Same value - even in 64-bit instead of 32-bit.  Maybe the problem is that I'm trying to explain undefined behaviour, which is more or less by definition unexplainable (inexplicable).

```
+ cat xx.c
#include <stdio.h>

static void print_value(unsigned int c)
{
    unsigned char* cptr  = (unsigned char*)&c;
    printf("Integer value:  %10u\n", c);
    printf("Integer value:  0x%08X\n", c);
    printf("Dotted decimal: %u.%u.%u.%u \n", *cptr, *(cptr+1), *(cptr+2), *(cptr+3));
}

static void scan_value(const char *str, const char *fmt, const char *tag)
{
    unsigned int c;
    printf("Indirect operations (%s):\n", tag);
    fmt = "%d";
    if (sscanf(str, fmt, &c) != 1)
        printf("Conversion failed for %s (format %s \"%s\")\n", str, tag, fmt);
    else
        print_value(c);
}

int main(void)
{
    const char str[] = "2249459722";
    unsigned int c = 2249459722U;

    printf("Direct operations:\n");
    print_value(c);
    scan_value(str, "%d", "signed");
    scan_value(str, "%u", "unsigned");

    return(0);
}
```

Using the function argument like this means GCC cannot spot the bogus format any more.

```
+ gcc -o xx.32 -m32 -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes xx.c


+ ./xx.32
Direct operations:
Integer value:  2249459722
Integer value:  0x8614080A
Dotted decimal: 10.8.20.134 
Indirect operations (signed):
Integer value:  2249459722
Integer value:  0x8614080A
Dotted decimal: 10.8.20.134 
Indirect operations (unsigned):
Integer value:  2249459722
Integer value:  0x8614080A
Dotted decimal: 10.8.20.134
```

The results are consistent here.

```
+ gcc -o xx.64 -m64 -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes xx.c


+ ./xx.64
Direct operations:
Integer value:  2249459722
Integer value:  0x8614080A
Dotted decimal: 10.8.20.134 
Indirect operations (signed):
Integer value:  2249459722
Integer value:  0x8614080A
Dotted decimal: 10.8.20.134 
Indirect operations (unsigned):
Integer value:  2249459722
Integer value:  0x8614080A
Dotted decimal: 10.8.20.134
```

And these are the same as the 32-bit case.  I'm officially bemused.  The main observations remain accurate - be careful, heed compiler warnings (and elicit compiler warnings), and don't assume that "all the world runs on Intel chips" (it used to be "don't assume that all the world is a VAX", once upon a long time ago!).

Comment: Good point. I thought to mention that in my edit, but I didn't think it would be understood.

Comment: The cause for the "unsigned only in C90" warning is that the rules about what the type of an integer literal in C is between C90 and C99.  In C90, the types "tried" are `int`, `long int` and `unsigned long int`.  In C99, the types are `int`, `long int` and `long long int`.  The constant `2249459722` is of type `unsigned long int` in C90 and `long long int` in C99 on your machine.  Adding `U` makes it unsigned everywhere.

Comment: Technically, the `printf()` functions can fail and should be checked too.  However, it is unusual to do so in example code - whereas checking inputs such as the `sscanf()` (or `scanf()` in the original) is crucial, even in example code.

Comment: Surely you meant `!= 1` and not `!= 0` in your `scanf()` call?

Comment: @Jonathan: Can you tell me the size of `int`, `long int` and `long long int` on your Solaris machine?  Just curious.

Comment: @Alok: under 'gcc' and 'gcc -m32', it is 4/4/8; under 'gcc -m64', it is 4/8/8.  I think that the makefile in the directory where I built the test program uses '-m64' by default.

Comment: @Jonathan: You will hate me for it, but in your `yy.c`, your `sscanf` call scans `"2249559722"`, not `str`, which is `"2249459722"`.  See the difference? 2249 **4** 59722 vs 2249 **5** 59722. Now? :-)

Comment: @Alok: well spotted - and absolutely no hate involved!  Indeed, it is a relief to know there's a rational reason for the issue.  I'm not sure why the scanf() is not generating an error, though.  I don't plan to amend my answer at the moment.  And I did remember noting at some point that I was not using the string I'd created...but I didn't fix it.  Oh well, ç'est la vie, comme on dit.

Comment: `scanf()` doesn't generate an error in case of overflow.  The behavior is undefined.  So, `int c; sscanf("123456789012345678901234567890", "%d", &c);` will (may) return 1, and `c` may contain anything.

Comment: @Alok: the dark corners of the C standard are indeed dark and twisty.  Even the spec for strtol() et al is hard to use: if the 'subject string' value is too big, you get the appropriate min/max integer value (LONG_MIN for negative, LONG_MAX for positive) and errno set to ERANGE.  I'd really rather have: `extern errno_t str_to_long(const char *str, char *end, int base, long *result);` with the return value being 0 for OK and ERANGE or other values on error (`errno_t` is defined in TR 24731-1 - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/ for more on that standard technical report).

Answer (score 5):

%d is for signed integers

%u is for unsigned integers

#### Edit:

Please modify your program as follows to see how your input is really interpreted:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 unsigned int c ; 
 unsigned char* cptr  = (unsigned char*)&c ;
 while(1)
 {
  scanf("%d",&c) ;
  printf("Signed value: %d\n",c);
  printf("Unsigned value: %u\n",c);
  printf("%u.%u.%u.%u \n",*cptr, *(cptr+1), *(cptr+2), *(cptr+3) );
 }
}
```

What happens when you supply a number greater than INT_MAX is the left-most bit is 1. This indicates that it is a signed integer with a negative value. The number is then interpreted as it's [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)

Comment: Also you might want to consider some research about 2's complement.

Comment: It could be interpreted as two's complement, or ones' complement, or whatever the underlying encoding is.  Technically, `scanf()` could have done anything, since the behavior when the input doesn't fit in the data type is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your main question:

```
scanf("%d", &c);
```

`scanf()`'s behavior is undefined when the input being converted can't be represented to the data type.  `2249459722` on your machine doesn't fit in an `int`, so `scanf()` can do anything, including storing garbage in `c`.

In C, `int` type is guaranteed to be able to store values in the range `-32767` to `+32767`.  An `unsigned int` is guaranteed values between `0` and `65535`.  So, as such, `2249459722` need not fit in even an `unsigned int`.  `unsigned long`, however, can store values up to `4294967295` (2<sup>32</sup>−1), so you should use `unsigned long`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned long c ;
    unsigned char *cptr  = (unsigned char*)&c ;
    while(1)
    {
        if (scanf("%lu", &c) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error in scanf\n");
            return 0;
        }
        printf("Input value: %lu\n", c);
        printf("%u.%u.%u.%u\n", cptr[0], cptr[1], cptr[2], cptr[3]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you have a C99 compiler, you can `#include <inttypes.h>` and then use `uint32_t` instead of `unsigned long`.  The `scanf()` call becomes `scanf("%" SCNu32, &c);`

Answer (score 1):

The correct endianness-safe way to write this is

```
printf("Dotted decimal: %u.%u.%u.%u \n", (c >> 24) & 0xff, (c >> 16) & 0xff, (c >> 8) & 0xff, (c >> 0) & 0xff);
```