# In a C expression where unsigned int and signed int are present, which type will be promoted to what type?

Tags: c, integer-promotion

I have a query about data type promotion rules in C language standard.
The C99 says that:

*C integer promotions also require that "if an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int."*

My questions is in case of a C language expression where `unsigned int` and `signed int` are present, which type will be promoted to what type?

E.g. `int` cannot represent all the values of the `unsigned int` (values larger than `MAX_INT` values) whereas `unsigned int` cannot represent the -ve values, so what type is promoted to what in such cases?

Comment: looks like the last sentence of para 1 of 6.3.1.8 applies -- both are "converted" to unsigned int.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think the following answers your question:

> **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
>
> **1** When a value with integer type is
> converted to another integer type
> other than _Bool, if the value can be
> represented by the new type, it is
> unchanged.
>
> **2** Otherwise, if the new
> type is unsigned, the value is
> converted by repeatedly adding or
> subtracting one more than the maximum
> value that can be represented in the
> new type until the value is in the
> range of the new type.
>
> **3** Otherwise,
> the new type is signed and the value
> cannot be represented in it; either
> the result is implementation-defined
> or an implementation-defined signal is
> raised.

Comment: Does this mean that `uint32_t i = 70; (int16_t)i;` is *implementation defined*?

Comment: @nonsensickle: No, `(int16_t)i` must be 70, because 70 is in the range of `int16_t`.  You only get implementation-defined behavior if `i` is outside the range of `int16_t`.

Answer (score 46):

I think you are confusing two things. *Promotion* is the process by which values of integer type "smaller" that int/unsigned int are converted either to int or unsigned int.  The rules are expressed somewhat strangely (mostly for the benefit of handling adequately char) but ensure that value and sign are conserved.

Then there is the different concept of *usual arithmetic conversion* by which operands of arithmetic operators are converted to a common type.  It begins by promoting the operand (to either int or unsigned) if they are of a type smaller than int and then choosing a target type by the following process (for integer types, 6.3.1.8/1)

> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
>   integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is
>   converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
>
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>   signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type.
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent
>   all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then
>   the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>   corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

(Note that ISTR that those rules have changed slightly between C89 and C99)

Comment: C99 made an explicit use of the term "rank" of an integral type. Also, see my comment to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032744/unexpected-behavior-when-printing-4-byte-integer-byte-by-byte/2032769#2032769

Comment: `exprimed` yeesh that took me on a wild Wikipedia ride to look up its definition.