# Hidden narrowing conversion from int to uint8_t

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, narrowing

Consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <cstdint>

class A
{
public:

    explicit A(uint8_t p_a){ m_a = p_a; };
    uint8_t get_a() const {return m_a;}

private:

    uint8_t m_a;
};

int main()
{
    A a {0x21U};
    A aa{0x55U};

    uint8_t mask{a.get_a() | aa.get_a()};

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this (`gcc 5.4.0`) I get the following error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:20:28: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘(int)(a.A::get_a() | aa.A::get_a())’ from ‘int’ to ‘uint8_t {aka unsigned char}’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
     uint8_t mask{a.get_a() | aa.get_a()};
```

I don't really understand why there is any narrowing at all. The `int` type is never used anywhere in my code, everything is written in terms of `unsigned char`s. Even if I explicitly cast to `unsigned char` I get the error:

```
uint8_t mask{static_cast<uint8_t>(a.get_a()) | static_cast<uint8_t>(aa.get_a())};
```

In fact, to solve this, I need to remove the `{}`-initialization. Then it works:

```
uint8_t mask = a.get_a() | aa.get_a();
```

Why is this necessary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer promotion - what are the steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255818/integer-promotion-what-are-the-steps)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were close with this:

```
uint8_t mask{static_cast<uint8_t>(a.get_a()) | static_cast<uint8_t>(aa.get_a())};
```

But `a.get_a()` and `aa.get_a()` are already `uint8_t`, so the cast does nothing.

It's the `|` operation that:

- converts both operands to `int` (after you can do anything about it)
- evaluates to an `int`

So it's the whole expression you now need to subsequently convert:

```
uint8_t mask{static_cast<uint8_t>(a.get_a() | aa.get_a())};
```

You were also right to try dropping the `{}`-initialisation, which is probably what I'd do too. You just don't need its strictness here.

```
uint8_t mask = a.get_a() | aa.get_a();
```

This is clear, concise and correct.

Answer (score 4):

Most binary arithmetic operations including the `|` bitwise-or that appears here force their subexpressions to be promoted, which is to say they will be at least `int` or `unsigned int` in rank.

C++ 17 [expr] paragraph 11:

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result. This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*, which are defined as follows:
>
> - If either operand is of scoped enumeration type, ...
> - If either operand is of type `long double`, ...
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `double`, ...
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `float`, ...
> - Otherwise, the integral promotions shall be performed on both operands. Then the following rules shall be applied to the promoted operands: ...

The [integral promotions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) here are what cause the `get_a()` values to change from `uint8_t` to `int`.  So the result of the `|` expression is also an `int`, and narrowing it to initialize another `uint8_t` is ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Integral promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) case:

> [prvalues](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue) of small integral types (such as `char`) may be converted to
>   prvalues of larger integral types (such as `int`).

`a.get_a() | aa.get_a()` - this is prvalue expression

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: @PasserBy, why not? It is definitely integral promotion with prvalue expression.

Comment: This does answer the question

Comment: The promotion happens on the operands of `|`, not the result.

Comment: It does not answer the question, but it is the first half of an answer that might.

Answer (score 0):

List initialization is more strict and this is why you get warning.

```
uint8_t mask{a.get_a() | aa.get_a()};
```

The expression inside the braces

```
auto i = a.get_a() | aa.get_a(); // i is int
```

is promoted to `int` and since `int` cannot entirely fit into `uint8_t`, the narrowing warning is issued based on [this rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

> If the initializer clause is an expression, implicit conversions are
>   allowed as per copy-initialization, except if they are narrowing (as
>   in list-initialization) (since C++11).

Comment: The promotion happens on the operands of `|`, not the result.

Comment: @aschepler: In a sense, it's both - the key point is that the result is an `int`, not a `uint8_t`.

Comment: @aschepler Yes, which leads to `i` being an `int`