# Unexpected macro evaluation

Tags: c++, macros

Why does this print `ffffffff`?

```
#define MYMACRO(n) (((uint16_t)0 - 1) >> (16 - (n)))
std::cout << std::hex << MYMACRO(1);
```

While this prints `1`?

```
#define MYMACRO(n) (((uint32_t)0 - 1) >> (32 - (n)))
std::cout << std::hex << MYMACRO(1);
```

I tried it with GCC and cpp.sh.

Comment: The usual arithmetic conversions. Presumably, `uint16_t` is promoted to `int` (which happens to be 32-bit).

Comment: It's because 1 has type `int`.

Comment: Crucially, on your platform `int` is a larger/wider integral type than `uint16_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Integral Promotions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) happen in C++. Nonetheless, testing the expressions practically, isn't a bad idea to understand whats happening under the hood...

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main(){
#define MYMACRO(n) (((uint16_t)0 - 1) >> (16 - (n)))
    std::cout << std::hex << MYMACRO(1);

    std::cout << "\n-----\n";
#undef MYMACRO
#define MYMACRO(n) (((uint32_t)0 - 1) >> (32 - (n)))
    std::cout << std::hex << MYMACRO(1);

    std::cout << "\n--++++--\n";
    std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id<decltype((uint16_t)0)>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id<decltype((uint16_t)0 - 1)>().pretty_name() << std::endl;    
    std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id<decltype((uint32_t)0 - 1)>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
}
```

The *integer* type of the expression after the shift operator isn't relevant in our case. From the output of the above program as seen [**Live On Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdfafbca17f1032f)

```
ffffffff
-----
1
--++++--
unsigned short
int
unsigned int
```

Summarizes that:

- The sub-expression: `(uint16_t)0` yields an `unsigned short` as *usual* on most platforms
- The expression: `(uint16_t)0 - 1` yields a type of `int`; because of integer promotion rules. `1` is an integral constant of type `int`
- The expression: `(uint32_t)0 - 1)` yields a type of `unsigned int`; still because of [*usual arithmetic conversions*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#11). an `unsigned int` is considered larger than an `int`

Comment: Is there a way to do this calculation in uint16_t while getting the expected 1?

Comment: @Silicomancer, Yes, you can.... Cast the whole expression to be of type `uint16_t` .... By defining your macro like this: `#define MYMACRO(n) ( (uint16_t)((uint16_t)((uint16_t)0 - 1) >> (16 - (n))))`

Comment: @M.M By saying "the resulting type of a C++ expression can be different from one *sub-expression* to its enclosing *expression*" - I took it from the view of treating *sub-expressions* in isolation. For example, the [tenary `?:` operator](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond) has some funny rules in there too... Is it wrong to treat sub-expressions in isolation? I've removed that statement nonetheless.

Comment: @M.M, Thanks. Corrected the final bullet point [*usual arithmetic conversions*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#11)... I am learning too. :-). Can you please respond to my question in the previous comment? Thanks

Comment: @WhiZTiM one of the good things about expressions in C and C++ is that they're independent of context  - an expression has a type that doesn't change depending on where it's used

Comment: @WhiZTiM: These conversion rules exist to allow compilers to provide operator implementations for a small subset of possible types (or type combinations) only, is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

An explanation is in the [type-promotion-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954717/type-promotion-in-c).

> (§6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers):
>
> If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int; ... These are called the integer promotions.
>   All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

So for your first case `((uint16_t)0 - 1)` is converted to an `int` for the substraction's needs. So then the right shift operation is an arithmetic right shift instead of a logical right shift.

Comment: Is there a way to do this calculation in uint16_t while getting the expected 1?

Comment: Yes: cast the `1` to `uint16_t` as well.

Comment: @user268396: Will make no difference.

Comment: @Silicomancer: It is not possible to do the *calculation* in `uint16_t`. Regardless of what you do, the calculation itself will be done in `int`. What you can do is force the result back into `uint16_t` *after* the subtraction. Even after that it will promote back to `int`, but at least it won't drop into the negative area. E.g. use `((uint16_t) (0 - 1) >> (16 - (n)))`, which is the same as `((uint16_t) -1 >> (16 - (n)))`. Or, even better, `((uint16_t) ((uint16_t) -1 >> (16 - (n))))`

Comment: @AnT: Seems you are right. Even the following does not work: #define MYMACRO(n) ((((uint16_t)0) - ((uint16_t)1)) >> (((uint16_t)16) - ((uint16_t)n)))  I don't understand exactly why.

Comment: @AnT it is possible to cast to `unsigned int` instead of letting the compiler promote to `int` to get the desired behavior.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Yes, tat will work too. By my "not possible" I meant specifically "not possible to force the evaluation to stay in the domain of 16-bit type".