# Conversions between types in C

Tags: c, types, operators, unsigned, signed

I know that whenever an operator used on two operands which have different types, the results type would be the "dominant" type between the two operands.
For example, the result of
`(int) + (float)`
would be a float.
Another example would be:
`(char) + (double)`
and the result is double.

That is correct for signed variables and only signed variables.

But what happens when we involve signed variables with unsigned variables?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2280810/339222

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The details are in C11, 6.3.1.8. To summarize:

- If the unsigned type is equal-or-wider, the signed type is converted to unsigned.
- Otherwise, if the signed type can hold all the values of the unsigned type, the unsigned type is converted to the signed type.
- Otherwise, both are converted to the to the unsigned version corresponding to the signed type.

By "wider" I mean "has higher conversion rank".

Examples (on some particular architecture, e.g. `sizeof(short) == 2` and `sizeof(long) == sizeof(unsigned int) = 4`):

```
int + unsigned int     => unsigned int  (first rule, equal rank)

long + unsigned short  => long          (second rule, long contains u. short)

long + unsigned int    => unsigned long (third rule)
```