# sizeof() operator in if-statement

Tags: c, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    if (sizeof(int) > -1)
        printf("True");
    else
        printf("False");
}
```

It prints `False`. Why doesn't sizeof() return a value in the `if`?

Comment: Enable your compiler warnings.

Comment: `(sizeof(int) > -1)` = `(4u > -1)` = `(4u > -1u)` = `(4u > -1u)` or `(4u > 4294967295uu)` because `-1u == 4294967295u` = `False` = `0`

Comment: `int main()`. not just `main()`.

Answer (score 55):

1. `sizeof` is not a function,  it's an operator. The parentheses are not part of the operator's name.
2. It's failing because the value generated has the unsigned type `size_t`, which causes "the usual arithmetic conversions" in which `-1` is converted to unsigned, in which case it's a very large number.

Basically you're comparing `4 > 0xffffffffu`, or something close to that at least. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280663/in-a-c-expression-where-unsigned-int-and-signed-int-are-present-which-type-will) for details.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is no integer promotion here, but rather _balancing_ (formally called "_the usual arithmetic conversions_").

Comment: converting `-1` to an unsigned integer type always yields the maximum value, even if the representation isn't two's complement

Comment: Your first point is true, but irrelevant. It would have been the same with a function returning `size_t`.

Comment: Just for nit-pickings sake: if `sizeof sizeof 1 < sizeof 1`, `sizeof(int)>-1` would be `true`.

Comment: @ugoren Yes, of course. I just strive to, uh, teach people this fact, since it's quite annoying that so many people who program C seem to misunderstand it. Probably sign of my hubris.

Answer (score 24):

Unsigned and signed integer promotion (rather "usual arithmetic conversions", to be more precise). `sizeof` yields a value of type `size_t`, and when compared to an unsigned value (which `size_t` is), -1 is promoted to that type, and overflows and becomes **huge.**

Unsigned integer overflow has well-defined behavior and is to be taken as modulo `2 ^ width`, where `width` is the number of bits in the particular unsigned integer type. So, if you have a 32-bit wide `size_t` and `int`, for example, your comparison will be equivalent with

```
if (4 > 4294967295u)
```

which is obviously false.

Comment: Great answer, but wouldn't it be underflowing rather than overflowing?

Comment: @C0deH4cker Well, it all depends on how you interpret it :) I prefer "underflow" to be used for floating-point numbers, when some `x < epsilon` number becomes zero. "Overflow" is easier to grasp here if you think of the phenomenon in terms of modulo arithmetic (that's how it's defined anyway).

Comment: Ah okay, this answer (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/32893/is-int-min-1-an-underflow-or-overflow) explains it and also why I was confused.

Answer (score 13):

- The operands of the > operator in the if statement are `sizeof(int)` and `-1`.
- `sizeof(int)` is of type `size_t`, which is guaranteed to be an unsigned integer. In practice, `size_t` will most likely be at least as big as `unsigned int` on any system out there.
- `-1` is of type `int`, which is equivalent to `signed int`.
- No integer promotions occur, as both operands are of large enough integer types.
- Then the two operands are *balanced* according to a C rule formally called *the usual arithmetic conversions*.

These state (C11 6.3.1.8):

> ...
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
>   represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is converted
>   to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise, both
>   operands are converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to
>   the type of the operand with signed integer type.

- The latter of the above will happen, since a (signed) `int` cannot fit all values of a `size_t`.
- Thus `-1` is converted to an unsigned integer. In practice, `size_t` is most likely equivalent to either unsigned int or unsigned long. Whatever happens when you store -1 in such a variable is implementation-defined behavior.
- On a two's complement computer (99.9% of all computers in the world), -1 will be interpreted as `0xFFFFFFFF` (the number of FF depends on the size of an int on the given system).
- `4 > 0xFFFFFFFF` evaluates to false.

Comment: "Whatever happens when you store -1 in such a variable is implementation-defined behavior." Umm, the only implementation-dependent thing here is the width of `size_t`. converting `-1` to an unsigned type is mandated to result in the maximum value of that type by the standard.

Comment: @DanielFischer What I meant with that, is that the manner of signed integer behavior is impl.defined. C allows two's complement, one's complement and so on.

Comment: Where "and so on" expands to "signed magintude" or "sign and magnitude", depending on which name you prefer. So whether the conversion is just a truncation/reinterpretation/sign-extension or changes the bit-pattern in a different way is implementation-defined, yes. But that's pretty irrelevant, isn't it? The important thing is the result.

Comment: @DanielFischer The result depends on the manner of signedness. -1 would give you 0xFFFFFFFE. Since I used 0xFFFFFFFF in my example, I wanted to point out that strictly speaking, -1 is not guaranteed to be 0xFFFFFFFF. Otherwise someone would post a comment and whine about that, since C allows obscure signedness formats as well.

Comment: While the bit pattern of `-1` need not be `0xFF..F`, the result of the conversion of `-1` (from a signed integer type) to an unsigned integer type always (well, unless the width is not a multiple of 4) has the bit pattern `0xFF...F`. That's mandated by the standard [modulo the as-if rule].

Comment: Sorry for replying to an old answer - I came here from a question that was marked as a duplicate of this question. I cannot find anything in the standard that guarantees that `size_t` will be at least as big as `unsigned int`. I think it is only guaranteed to be as big as `unsigned short`. So it is technically possible for a bizarre, but legal implementation of C to evaluate `sizeof(int) > -1` as `1` instead of the more typical `0`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yeah, I actually believe that's true, at least in theory. In practice, it would be a very weird system to make `size_t` smaller than the default `int` type. But I can fix the post.

Comment: @Lundin. Yes, it would be bizarre. I made a mistake too. It's not guaranteed to be as bit as `unsigned short`. It's only guaranteed that it's maximum value is at least 65535.

Answer (score 2):

Sizeof is an operator that results in an unsigned long int. Hence, when you compare unsigned long int with -1, which is stored as `0xffffffff` (size of int is 4 bytes).

-1 is signed integer by default. But, in comparison between signed int and unsigned int, the compiler goes with implicit typecasting of signed int to unsigned int. This results in unsigned -1 to be approximately equal to 4.6giga value.

Hence, the output is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Just test this and see for yourself

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
    unsigned int a=4;
    int b = -1;
    //this is what you're doing
    printf("%u vs %u\n", a, (unsigned int)b);
    //this is what you want to do instead
    printf("%d vs %d\n", (int)a, b);
}
```