# Why is this happening with the sizeof operator when comparing with a negative number?

Tags: c, sizeof, implicit-conversion

What's really happening here? The output now is "False":

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     if (sizeof(int) > any_negative_integer)
         printf("True");
     else
         printf("False");
     return 0;
}
```

If I change it to:

```
if (sizeof(int) < any_negative_integer)
```

the output is "True".

Update: the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293749/sizeof-operator-in-if-statement) has already been asked, I could not find it before asking.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[sizeof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) returns `size_t` which is unsigned and so `-1` is being converted to a very large unsigned number. Using the right warning level would have helped here, `clang` with the `-Wconversion` or `-Weverything`(*[note this is not for production use](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122608/clang-warning-flags-for-objective-c-development/124574#124574)*) flags warns us:

```
warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-conversion]
   if (sizeof(int) > -1)
                   ~ ^~
```

For `gcc` you receive a similar warning using the `-Wextra` flag:

```
warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
    if (sizeof(int) > -1)
                    ^
```

For reference, we know *size_t* is *unsigned* from the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `7.17` *Common definitions*  which says:

```
 size_t
```

> which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator;[...]

Note, it does not specify anything else about the type, in my specific case it happens to be *unsigned long* but it does not have to be.

The conversion of `-1` is due to the *usual arithmetic conversion* covered in section `6.3.1.8` *Usual arithmetic conversions* which says:

> [...]
>
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>   signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type.
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent
>   all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then
>   the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>   corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

So the only time `-1` would not be converted to an unsigned value would be if *int* could represent all the values of *size_t*, which is not the case here.

Why `-1` ends up being a large unsigned value, actually it ends up being being the max value of the unsigned type is due to section `6.3.1.3` *Signed and unsigned integers* which says:

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.<sup>49)</sup>

So we end up with:

```
-1 + (UMAX + 1)
```

which is:

```
UMAX
```

and thus end up with:

```
if (sizeof(int) > UMAX )
```

Comment: damn I didn't even think of that, thanks I can accept it after 10 minutes

Comment: Just be careful, the standard says nothing on the relative sizes of `int` and `size_t`

Comment: I used codeblocks by default all the flags were unchecked, now I've enabled all compiler warnings

Comment: @akki `-pedantic` is a good flag since it warns about extensions which are common in both `gcc` and `clang`.

Comment: yeah when I changed `any_negative_integer` to 64 bit integer it worked as expected, thanks for elaborating :)

Answer (score 2):

Because `sizeof()` returns a `size_t`, an unsigned type. Comparing signed and unsigned types can give surprising results due to implicit casting before the comparison.

Comment: There is no such thing as “implicit casting”. A cast is a syntactic construct and is never implicit. You mean implicit conversion.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, what do you call `double d; int i; d = i;` then?

Comment: What part of “You mean implicit conversion” do you not understand?