# Why does this code return as false in C

Tags: c

Ok, trying to understand why the if statement below is false.  I've turned it inside out and can't understand what is going on here.

```
#define SIZE (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int))

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

    if ( -1 <= SIZE )
        printf( "true" );
    else
        printf( "false" );

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: A better macro would be 
`#define SIZE (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*(arr)))`

Comment: As far as I can tell, your program exhibits **implementation defined behavior**, depending on relative integer rank of `int` and `size_t`. I don't know any implementation with rank `int` > rank `size_t`, which is neccessary to print `true` in your example.

Comment: You can use no-prototype style, but then you are in pre-C99 backwards-compatibility mode. You really don't want to go there. Use `int main(int argc, char** argv)`, `int main(void)` or compatible.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Why is this happening with the sizeof operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047158/why-is-this-happening-with-the-sizeof-operator)

Answer (score 12):

It *prints* `false` because of signed/unsigned mismatch in the comparison.

The result of `sizeof` is a `size_t` value, which is unsigned. When the `int` value `-1` is compared to that, the integer is interpreteted as a very large unsigned value.

The C99 draft standard expresses this like so:

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>   signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type.

Here, the `size_t` is at least `unsigned int` which makes it rank equal to or out-rank `int`, and thus cause the `int` to be converted to `size_t`.

Also, `main()` really does return `int`, I don't understand why you edited that out.

Comment: So, the compiler is converting the int literal to unsigned, same as size_t?

Comment: `(unsigned int)-1` ends up usually as `0xFFFFFFFF`

Comment: Is there any normative text guaranteeing `-1` will be converted to `((size_t)-1)` instead of `SIZE` to `((int)SIZE)`?

Comment: @DaveBlack No, the *literal* is never converted, it's just the value of evaluating that literal at that particular place in the code.

Comment: @Deduplicator I think so, that's what the rank talk I added is about.

Comment: @Agent_L as I explained in the answer linked in my comment it will always be UMAX.

Comment: As far as I can say, it is not. `size_t` may have higher, lower or equal rank to `int`. So it is not guaranteed.

Comment: You should not think too much about "conversions of value". Both signed and unsigned ints are just few bytes in the memory. Tt's how compiler treats them at given time. This happens here, the -1 gets rather "interpreted as" than "converted to" unsigned.

Comment: @Agent_L: That's a conversion, even if you tell yourself it is only an interpretation.

Comment: i got 4294967295d, 0xFFFFFFFF.  yup.

Comment: @unwind: `unsigned` or bigger unsigned type. You really cannot say from context.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Which is enough to make the literal -1 convert to unsigned.

Comment: @Deduplicator : That's mere interpretation, even if language spec calls it a conversion. The spec is very old and unfortunate phrasing confuses ppl who came from higher lvl languages, where variables actually carry their own type and conversion is entirely different process than just reinterpretation.

Comment: @DaveBlack That is not up to you to decide, `main()` *must* return `int`, by definition. If you're doing something else, you're not programming in standard-compliant C.