# Why the sizeof operator is giving unexpected result in c?

Tags: c, sizeof, bit

In the below code if I stores the value of the sizeof(int) in a variable int a, and then compares it with -1 it shows "Yes" as a answer, otherwise "No"?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
if (sizeof(int) > -1)
    printf("Yes");
else
    printf("No");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question (and your desired answer) is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047158/why-is-this-happening-with-the-sizeof-operator

Comment: change to `if ((int)sizeof(int) > -1)`