# bit representation of unsigned int a = -1

Tags: c, integer-promotion

What is the bit representation of `unsigned int  x =-1;`
Can we assign unsigned int with a negative integer?

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main(){
    unsigned int x = -1; 
    int y = ~0; 
    if(x == y) 
        printf("same"); 
    else
        printf("not same"); 
    return 0;
}
```

output :

> same

and how is it possible, x being unsigned

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int  main()     
{

unsigned int x = -4; 
if (x == -4)
   printf("true");
else 
   printf("FALSE");
}
```

output:

> true

Comment: unsigned can not be negative :)
when you wrote the word "unsigned" you do not think it means?

Comment: The answer of your question is already in your example.

Comment: i mean, how -1 is represented in binary form. What is the logic that -1 and 1 are the same

Comment: -1 is always UMAX see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22801135/1708801) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047158/why-is-this-happening-with-the-sizeof-operator-when-comparing-with-a-negative-nu/22047204#22047204)

Comment: @larsmans: The language requires `(unsigned)(-1)` to produce `UNIT_MAX` on all platforms, regardless of whether they use 2's coimplement or not.

Comment: `~0`, on the other hand, only yields -1 if the implementation uses 2's complement (and for sake of completeness, `~0` may be a trap representation (otherwise, it's negative zero) for 1's complement).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When an `unsigned int` value is compared to `int` value, the `int` value is implicitly converted to `unsigned int` type. The result of that conversion is [congruent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) to the original value modulo 2<sup>N</sup>, where `N` is the number of value-forming bits in `unsigned int`. This modulo equals to `UINT_MAX + 1`.

For this reason initialization

```
unsigned int x = -1;
```

initializes `x` with some unsigned value [congruent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) to `-1` modulo `UINT_MAX + 1`. Incidentally, this is nothing else than `UINT_MAX`. This value has `1` in each value-forming bit of `unsigned int` object. It works that way with any unsigned type.

Expression `~0` is evaluated in the domain of `signed int` type, and then `y` is implicitly converted to `unsigned int` in `x == y` comparison. Apparently, on your platform the conversion produces the same `unsigned int` value with all value-forming bits set to `1`. Hence the equality.

Initialization

```
unsigned int x = -4;
```

initializes `x` with some unsigned value [congruent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) to `-4` modulo `UINT_MAX + 1`. In comparison `x == -4` the right-hand side is converted to unsigned type by the very same rules. Hence the equality.

Comment: Exactly.  “When a value with integer type is converted to […] unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.” (C11, §6.3.1.3).

Answer (score 2):

> and how is it possible, x being unsigned

This is the "usual arithmetic conversions" -- the operands on either side of the `==` have different types, so they must be converted to the same types first. The rule for types of int or larger when the types differ only by signedness is that unsigned wins, so this converts `-4` into the unsigned equivalent value, just as it did when you assigned `-4` into an unsigned integer.

For more information, see [How do promotion rules work when the signedness on either side of a binary operator differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770258/how-do-promotion-rules-work-when-the-signedness-on-either-side-of-a-binary-opera)

Comment: @mafso: Ah, I mean types of the same size. The nitty gritty details are at the link I added.

Answer (score 0):

in int negative integers are stored in 2's complement.

suppose we have a data type say of 4 bits.

the first bit 0 represents that the integer is positive otherwise negative, so its max value is 0111 i.e 7

so 1 can be written as 0001

and for -1, it has to be written in its 2's complement, since it is negative ;

-1 = ~(0001) +1 = (1110) + 1 = 1111;

so making this data type unsigned reads -1 as 15.

Comment: Note that this is only true on 2's complement machines, which the C standard does not require.