# what's wrong? about integer, long in java

Tags: integer, long-integer

This is android code performs time calculation.
Please see the below code:

```
int test1 = 1000*60*60*24*7; // milliseconds of the week
long test = test1*4;
Log.d(String.valueof(test));
```

the printed value is the minus value...

```
int test1 = 1000*60*60*24*7; // milliseconds of the week
long test3 = test1;
long test = test3*4;
Log.d(String.valueof(test));
```

the printed value is plus value.

Why are these values different?

Answer (score 0):

probably type coercion order.  the first case is long = int * 4, the second is long = long * 4.  The value is larger than the largest possible positive signed 32-bit integer, so the long = int * 4 must be getting run as long = (long)(int * 4).  Explicitly casting to long before the multiplication should fix it:  long = int * 4L;

try `long test = (long)test1*4;`

Answer (score 0):

1000*60*60*24*7 = 604,800,000

604,800,000 * 4  = 2,419,200,000

The maximum value for an `int` is 2.147,483,647 (the [so-called Gangnam Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27275150/advice-on-unsigned-int-gangnam-style-edition)).

If you want to do this calculation, you have to do it in `long` so it does not overflow. At least before you start doing that last multiplication.

```
long test = test1*4;    // this is still an `int` multiplication

long test3 = test1;     // now it's `long`
long test = test3*4;

// or like this
long test = test1 * (long)4;

// or
long test = test1 * 4L;
```