# Getting a <' : signed/unsigned mismatch

Tags: c++, strlen

The error is when I compare the value an int to the strnlen of a char with a set string length. what I am doing is searching the string for a certain # and tracking if it is found or not.

```
for (value = 0; value < strlen(stringValue) && !searchFound; value++)
{

    if (stringValue[value] == searchDigit)
    {
        numberTimesSearchFound = numberTimesSearchFound + 1;

        //ends loops once it is found
        searchFound = true;

    } //end of string value if else loop}
```

Answer (score 1):

`strlen` returns `size_t` which is an unsigned type.  You compare this to `value` which is a signed type.  In C, values have to be of the same type to be compared, and the rule here is that `value` will be converted to `size_t` before the comparison.

In your code this is no problem (except for the case I mention later about INT_MAX), there are other situations where signed-unsigned comparisons do contain bugs.  [See here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047158/why-is-this-happening-with-the-sizeof-operator-when-comparing-with-a-negative-nu/22047204#22047204) .

Because of this possibility, some compilers warn about all signed-unsigned comparisons, so that you can manually check your code for bugs.

To get rid of this warning I'd suggest changing `value` to have type `size_t`.  If you go on to use `value` after the end of this code snippet then make sure that you weren't relying on any more signed-unsigned comparisons afterwards!

Ideally, scope it to the loop:

```
for ( size_t value = 0; ......
```

NB. If the string is longer than `INT_MAX` then your original code causes undefined behaviour when `value` is incremented beyond that; making `value` be `size_t` also fixes that problem.