# -1 not less than 12?

Tags: c, string, substring, assert

I have small program in C (substring):

```
char *str_sub(char *string, int from, int to) {
    assert(to < 0 || from < to);

    if (!(to < strlen(string))) {
        printf("%d %ld\n", to, strlen(string));
    }

    assert(from < strlen(string) && to < strlen(string));

    char *result = (char *) calloc(to - from + 1, 1);

    memcpy(result, &string[from], to);
    result[to] = '\0';
```

When I pass -1 to `to`, I want to make the function match to rest of the string, but that doesn't matter. Do you see the second assert? When I pass -1 to `to`, it will raise error and in the above condition it also says `false`, but it's just -1 and 12, and as we know from school, -1 < 12.

So where's the problem?

Comment: strlen returns size_t which is unsigned and therefore -1 will be converted and [-1 is always unsigned max](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22801135/1708801). Very similar to this [sizeof case here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22047204/1708801).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing variables with different signedness, so the representation of `-1` is not uniform between them.  See also @Shafik Yaghmour's SO answer referenced in the comments.

I can show the warnings from the compiler like so:

```
$ clang -Wsign-compare -c sign.c
sign.c:9:14: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-compare]
    if (!(to < strlen(string))) {
          ~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sign.c:13:17: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-compare]
    assert(from < strlen(string) && to < strlen(string));
           ~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/assert.h:89:5: note: expanded from macro 'assert'
  ((expr)                                                               \
    ^
sign.c:13:40: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-compare]
    assert(from < strlen(string) && to < strlen(string));
                                    ~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/assert.h:89:5: note: expanded from macro 'assert'
  ((expr)                                                               \
    ^

$ cat sign.c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

char *str_sub(char *string, int from, int to) {
    assert(to < 0 || from < to);

    if (!(to < strlen(string))) {
        printf("%d %ld\n", to, strlen(string));
    }

    assert(from < strlen(string) && to < strlen(string));

    char *result = (char *) calloc(to - from + 1, 1);

    memcpy(result, &string[from], to);
    result[to] = '\0';

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A many have said, `to < strlen(string)` compares `(size_t)-1 < strlen(string)`.  Since `size_t` is some unsigned type, `(size_t)-1` is a large positive value and this compare regularly fails.  [@Shafik Yaghmour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950509/1-not-less-than-12/32950755?noredirect=1#comment53725914_32950509)

To fix: take into account `size_t`.

```
char *str_sub(char *string, int from, int to) {
    assert(to < 0 || from < to);
    assert(from >= 0);

    size_t length = strlen(string);
    size_t uto = to < 0 ? length : to; 

    assert(from < uto);

    if (!(uto < strlen(string))) {
        printf("%zu %zu\n", uto, strlen(string));
    }

    assert(from < length && uto < length);

    char *result = malloc(uto - from + 1);

    // memcpy(result, &string[from], to);
    memcpy(result, &string[from], uto - from);
    // result[to] = '\0';
    result[uto - from] = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

Note: rather than all these `assert()`, suggest defining operation for all combinations of `from,to`.

Rather than `int` for `from` and `to`, use `size_t` and create `#define  MATCH_REST ((size_t)-1)`.  Example:

```
#define  MATCH_REST ((size_t)-1)

char *str_sub(const char *string, size_t from, size_t to) {
  size_t length = strlen(string);
  if (to > length) to = length;
  if (from > to) from = to;

  size_t diff = to - from;
  char *result = malloc(diff + 1);
  if (result) {
    memcpy(result, &string[from], diff);
    result[diff] = '\0';
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`strlen` returns a `size_t` (unsigned-related) variable, and before any comparision, both variables must have the same type. So, one of them must be cast to the other.

In your example, I'm sure `to` has been casted to `unsigned`, causing overflow (-1), and probably, you are comparing `strlen(string)` to the max representable unsigned integer (the probable result of the overflow).

So, the solution is:

```
char *str_sub(char *string, int from, int to) {
  assert(to < 0 || from < to);

  if (!(to < (int)strlen(string))) {
    printf("%d %ld\n", to, strlen(string));
  }

  assert(from < strlen(string) && to < (int)strlen(string));

  char *result = (char *) calloc(to - from + 1, 1);

  memcpy(result, &string[from], to);
  result[to] = '\0';
```

Or, to avoid recalculations:

```
char *str_sub(char *string, int from, int to) {
  int length = strlen(string);

  assert(to < 0 || from < to);

  if (!(to < length)) {
    printf("%d %ld\n", to, length);
  }

  assert(from < length && to < length);

  char *result = (char *) calloc(to - from + 1, 1);

  memcpy(result, &string[from], to);
  result[to] = '\0';
```

Or, to do safe castings, for too long `string`s (thanks for remarking it, @chux):

```
char *str_sub(char *string, int from, int to) {
  size_t length = strlen(string);

  assert(length > 0);
  assert(to < 0 || from < to);

  if (!(to > 0 && to < length))
    printf("%d %lu\n", to, length);

  assert(from < length);
  assert(to < 0 || to < length);

  char *result = (char *) calloc(to - from + 1, 1);

  memcpy(result, &string[from], to);
  result[to] = '\0';
```

Comment: not really overflow, but interpreting 0xffffffff as unsigned max, rather than -1... just being a little pedantic.

Comment: `int length = strlen(string);` fails for long strings.

Comment: @chux Pedantic mode again: It doesn't "fail". It's undefined behaviour if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The compare operator assumes that both variables you compare are of the same type. This beeing not the case, the binary representation of "-1" unsigned as a signed variable is quite not "-1", but instead the max value of the variable.