# Why does the following loop execute

Tags: c++

```
std::vector<int> tmp = ...
for(int i = 0; i <= tmp.size() - 3; i+=2){
    std::cout << "i: " << i << " , tmp.size(): " << tmp.size() << std::endl;
    if(tmp[i] == tmp[i+1]){
        final.push_back(tmp[i] * 2);
    }else{
        final.push_back(tmp[i]);
        final.push_back(tmp[i + 1]);
    }   
    std::cout << "\ntmp.size() at the end of loop: " << tmp.size() << "\n";         
}
```

I have the following output:

[image]

Why does the loop execute as `i` is clearly much much bigger than `tmp.size()` ?

Comment: i should never be int: it should be vector<T>::size_type

Comment: Looks like [usual arithmetic conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22047204/1708801) try `-Wconversion`

Comment: Change to `i + 3 <= tmp.size();`.

Comment: Pity the code is not a [mcve]. Other than that it's a rather interesting question.

Comment: I edited to add a definition of `tmp` based on the comment. Voting to re-open the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `tmp.size()` is `1`, subtracting 3 from it produces a negative value. That is, subtraction would produce a negative value if it weren't for `tmp.size()` being `size_t`, which is unsigned.

When an unsigned is about to go negative on subtraction, it "wraps around" to a very large value. That is why your loop fails to stop. It also explains the "signed to unsigned comparison" warning produced by the compiler<sup>*</sup>, which should have put you on high alert.

To avoid this problem, move subtraction to the other side, and make it addition:

```
for (size_t i = 0 ; i+3 <= tmp.size() ; i += 2) {
    ...
}
```

<sup>*</sup> If you did not get that warning, change the settings on your compiler to warn you about everything. This saves a lot of time spent in debugging many common problems that are easily detectable by compilers.

Answer (score 2):

Because your `tmp.size()` is only 1, in the `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= tmp.size() - 3; i+=2) { /* ... */ }
```

`tmp.size() - 3` becomes a negative number but with unsigned type, thus a huge number. That's why your `i` won't stop increasing even it's extremely large.