# How do I solve this issues with Arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I am passing an array to a function whose size is determined by the user itself.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
void mapper(int a[], int size);
int main ()
{
    int n;
    printf("Please provide the number of inputs\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int array[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }
    mapper(array,n);
    return 0;

}
void mapper (int a[], int size)
{
  for (int i=0; i<size;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<sizeof(a[i]);j++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

When I run this program I get an error called the comparison of signed integer to unsigned integer. Why is it so? Is it because I have passed a[] as an argument and am later using a[i]?

How do you pass an array as an argument to a function whose size is to be determined?

Comment: The [`sizeof` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) returns `size_t`. `size_t` is a flavor of `unsigned` which has the size of pointers on your platform (e.g. on 64 bit size of `size_t` is 64 bit as well).

Comment: Usually, comparing signed with unsigned yields a **warning**. Do you really get an error? What compiler settings have you used?

Comment: @Sheff most companies force to treat warnings as errors as programmers tend to ignore them.

Comment: `a` is a one dimensional array. What do you intend `sizeof(a[i])` to return? The size of type `int` on your architecture (that's what it does in real life)?

Comment: Potential duplicate of [A warning - comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660901/a-warning-comparison-between-signed-and-unsigned-integer-expressions).

Comment: @Scheff: The C standard does not require that `size_t` be the size of pointers. Indeed, pointers of different types may have different sizes within a C implementation, in which case it is impossible for `size_t` to be the same size as all pointers.

Comment: Why those downvotes?

Comment: @alk because there is no mcve? (i didn't downvote)

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are always that accurate... Indeed, I found this in [std::size_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) (C++) _On many platforms (an exception is systems with segmented addressing) std::size_t can safely store the value of any non-member pointer, in which case it is synonymous with std::uintptr_t._ but not such note for [size_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) (C). I must admit I use C++ in daily work and follow C to keep in touch (and become aware to the peculiar differences). ;-)

Comment: @P__J__ That's why I've asked for the compiler settings...

Comment: @hnefatl The _Potential duplicate_ is for C++. Considering that both communities are often annoyed when C and C++ are not strictly separated as two languages, there better should be recommended one with [tag:c]... May be, this one: [SO: sizeof() operator in if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17293749/7478597)

Comment: @Scheff: [Citing the C11 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19p2): "*size_t

which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator*" for completeness. ;)

Comment: @alk I believe I got it... ;-)

Comment: @alk: My impression is a number of people vote down any question that they consider makes an obvious error or overlooks an obvious solution or course of action, where “obvious” is determined by the voter’s knowledge and not the asker’s. It is not a good behavior. It is a strange ability of humans to be knowledgeable about a technical matter and simultaneously oblivious to the work that got them there, unaware of their own previous ignorance, and unforgiving of others striding on the same path they previously traversed.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run this program I get an error called the comparison of signed integer to unsigned integer. Why is it so?

You get that error because in

> ```
> for(int j=0; j<sizeof(a[i]);j++)
> ```

`sizeof` yields a value of type `size_t` which is an unsigned type and you compare it to an `int`.