# Counter in C Language

Tags: c, arrays, int, sizeof

I'm mainly an electronics hardware guy, but I've learned the basics of D from a friend, so I decided I'd pick up a more standard language like C. So, any advice would be great.
Basically, I'm using the integer 'phew' as a counter, to reverse all numbers. Super basic, but I'm having trouble finding the way to do this in C. My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     int input;
     int phew;
     printf("Binary Number: ");
     scanf("%d", &input);
     while(phew < sizeof(input))
     {
          if(input[phew] == 0)
               printf("1");
          else
               printf("0");
          phew++;
      }
      return 0;
}
```

And the compiler error was:

```
helloworld.c: In function ‘main’:
helloworld.c:11:11: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
if(input[phew] == 0)
        ^
```

Comment: `[]` is a subscript operator and can only be used with array and pointer datatypes, `input` is neither.

Comment: The compiler tells you `input` is not an array, which is how you are trying to use it. You also have *undefined behaviour* by using `phew` before it has been given a value. Local (automatic) variables are not initialised.

Comment: Also, variable `phew` is uninitialized. Consider doing `int phew = 0`.

Comment: Even if `input` *was* an array, `while(phew < sizeof(input))` is incorrect, that is not the number of elements.

Comment: An int isn't an array of bits though you can use bitwise operators to extract the individual bits. Reading a book is a very good idea. With your hardware background you should pick it up fairly easily.

Comment: Try [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format) about printing in binary.

Comment: I'd suggest using more precise language in your question, as "reverse all numbers" doesn't really make sense. Reverse what? The digits? The order? it looks like what you are trying to do is "print the bits of an integer in ascending order of place value", so I've written an answer based on that assumption.

Comment: I did a rollback since rants about site usage should not go into questions/answers. If you feel that you have a different definition of what this site is about than other users, then raise debate at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ and not inside your own technical question.

Comment: That being said I would suspect that you might be coming from VHDL, Verilog and similar hardware languages? If so, then that's the source of all the problems. High-level programming languages are very different, since they are sequential rather than parallel.

Comment: still, I did not get the logic for printing `1` when the match is `0`. hmmm..

Comment: @SouravGhosh Ah, possibly "invert" was intended instead of "reverse". I missed that.

Comment: @trentcl no, you're right. I myself missed that. :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, in the below statement,

```
 while(phew < sizeof(input))
```

- invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as `phew` is an automatic local variable and not initialized. You need to initialize `phew` like `int phew = 0;`
- In this scenario, `sizeof(input)` is valid, but does not make any sense.

That said, you can only use the `[]` operator on an array type. In your case, `input` is an `int`, so you are not allowed to write `input[n]`.

to elaboate, quoting the `C11` standard, chapter §6.5.2.1

> #### Syntax
>
> *postfix-expression* `[` *expression* `]`

and the description

> One of the expressions shall have type *pointer to complete object type*, the other
>   expression shall have integer type, and the result has type *type*.

So, clearly, in your case `input` is not a *"pointer-to-type"*, hence the error.

To solve the issues,

1. You can change the type of `input` as `char input[32] = {0};`
2. change the scan statement as  `scanf("%29s", input);
3. add `while(phew < strlen(input))`

to make sense. You'll be needing `string.h` header file for that. Check details about [`strlen()` here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen).

You have to change it like

```
while(phew <  strlen(input) )
 {
      if(input[phew] == '0')  //ASCII 48, decimal
           printf("1");
      else
           printf("0");
      phew++;
  }
```

Comment: @WeatherVane was just addressing that part. Thanks. :)

Comment: `sizeof(input)` is NOT the number of elements. It's an `int` array not a `char` array.

Comment: He actually trying to index each ***bit*** of `input`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think the `char` array will roughly solve the issue, isn't it?

Comment: The question was not well phrased, but I think OP is trying to *reverse* a binary input, so yes, a char array will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `[]` to get bits of an integer in C; that operator only works on pointer values and an `int` is not a pointer. You may be familiar with Verilog, where bit vectors and integers are the same thing; but C doesn't have a syntax for accessing bits of an object and `[]` is only for accessing members of an array.

One correct way to do this is using a bit mask. For example:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof input)*CHAR_BIT; i++) {
    unsigned mask = 1 << i;
    if (input & mask) {
        putchar('1');
    } else {
        putchar('0');
    }
}
putchar('\n');
```

What this code does on each iteration of the loop is create an unsigned integer `mask` by [shifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) the number 1 into the `i`th place of the integer. Then `mask` is [bitwise-ANDed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) with `input` to give a value that is 0 if that bit is 0 in `input` (and otherwise some nonzero value equivalent to the place value of the bit). Don't forget to print out a newline at the end or the output may not be visible.

I'm using `unsigned` arithmetic here because `<<` can have implementation-defined or undefined behavior on signed numbers in C. `input` can be a regular (signed) `int` because it will be [promoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280663/in-a-c-expression-where-unsigned-int-and-signed-int-are-present-which-type-will) to `unsigned` by the `&` operator.

Also notice that I had to multiply `sizeof input` by `CHAR_BIT` (which is defined in `<limits.h>`) to get the number of *bits*; `sizeof` always measures sizes in *bytes*.

Also see [this C FAQ (20.7)](http://c-faq.com/misc/bitmanip.html) about bit manipulations.