# 8051 16 bit addition/multiplication result 16 bit instead of 32 bit

Tags: c, 16-bit, integer-arithmetic, integer-promotion

I have a problem. In this program the variable x should be set to 0x10000 but in both operations the result is 0.

This is not the main program but a test to find the reason for the error. I am currently making a 64 bit multiplier with hex input. I used 16-bit multiplication using Keil and Proteus

```
int main() {
    unsigned long int x = 0;
    x = 0x8000 * 0x2;
    x = 0x8000 + 0x8000;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To format code all you have to do is indent with four spaces.

Comment: How do you know what the result is? The code as is is not doing anything and I would just optimize this stuff away if I was your compiler.

Comment: Your compiler might be throwing away `x` since it's never used. What's the size of `unsigned long int`?

Comment: How do you know that the result is 0? Are you using a watch in a debugger?

Comment: i am using keil debugger to get the result and the size of unsigned long int is 32 bit

Comment: See also [reasons not to use 1000 * 1000 * 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637622/2410359).

Comment: Could use `x = 0x8000; x *= 2;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The literal `0x8000` is of type **`unsigned int`**. On your 16-bit machine, the `int` and therefore `unsigned int` is of the natural size of 16 bits, the smallest accepted by the C standard. The integer promotion rules say that the smaller width types are widened to `int` or `unsigned int`, but no further [(C11 n1570 6.3.1.1p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p2):

> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the integer promotions. 58) All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

An operand is widened from `int` or `unsigned int` only if the *other* operand has a greater rank.

Here, `0x8000` + `0x8000` is calculated using `unsigned int` which will wrap to 0, because the maximum value that can be represented in `unsigned int` is `0xFFFF`.

You should force at least one of the operands to **`unsigned long`** using either the suffix `UL`, or by adding an explicit cast:

```
int main() {
    unsigned long int x=0;
    /* unsigned long int * int */
    x = 0x8000UL * 0x2;

    /* unsigned long + unsigned int */
    x = (unsigned long)0x8000 + 0x8000;
    return 0;
}
```

---

See also [In a C expression where unsigned int and signed int are present, which type will be promoted to what type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2280663/918959) for general discussion.

Comment: @MohamedZaky you might consider [accepting this answer then](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/190417) ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear way (or that) the variable x should be 0x10000. x is a `unsigned long int`, but the values you assign to it are `unsigned int`. And if on that platform `int` is only 16 bit, both `0x8000 * 2` and `0x8000 + 0x8000` are 0.

Try using `0x8000L` (or better `0x8000UL`) for creating long literals at the first place.

Comment: The suffix is not required for last 3 standard revisions at least. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p5 . The constants will have the least type they will fit in.

Comment: i am multiplying 2 16 bit numbers and assigning the result in 32 bit variable

Comment: @EugeneSh. the suffix is required because unsigned int is **16 bits**, and unsigned ints are **not** promoted in arithmetic.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Right. Your answer is explaining it well.