# 32-Bit variable shifting in 8-bit MCU

Tags: c, avr

I'm using 32-bit variable for storing 4 8-bit values into one 32-bit value.

```
32_bit_buf[0]= cmd[9]<<16 | cmd[10]<<8| cmd[11] <<0;
```

`cmd` is of unsigned char type with data

```
cmd [9]=AA
cmd[10]=BB
cmd[11]=CC
```

However when 32-bit variable is printed I'm getting `0xFFFFBBCC`.

Architecture- 8-bit AVR Xmega

Language- C

Can anyone figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: The definition of these variables is significant. All values smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` first. `int` is signed, and when you push to the sign bit, the behaviour is undefined. Then the value gets sign-extended to the 32-bit buffer - even *its* definition is significant btw.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280663/in-a-c-expression-where-unsigned-int-and-signed-int-are-present-which-type-will

Comment: @AnttiHaapala the sign bit isn't the *immediate* problem here, but it *could* be the next one... added that to my answer.

Comment: @FelixPalmen well the sign bit UB is where those FFFF probably come from

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your architecture uses 16bit `int`, so shifting by 16 places is undefined. Cast your `cmd[9]` to a wider type, e.g. `(uint32_t)cmd[9] << 16` should work.

You should also apply this cast to the other components: When you shift `cmd[10]` by 8 places, you could shift into the sign-bit of the 16bit *signed* `int` your operands are automatically promoted to, leading to more strange/undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are trying to shift value in 8 bit container (unsigned char) and get a 32 bit. The 8-bit value will be expanded to `int` (16 bit), but this is still not enough. You can solve the issue in many ways, one of them for e.g. could be by using the destination variable as accumulator.

```
32_bit_buf[0] = cmd[9];
32_bit_buf[0] <<= 8;
32_bit_buf[0] |= cmd[10];
32_bit_buf[0] <<= 8;
32_bit_buf[0] |= cmd[11];
```

Comment: Sorry but there's no "8bit container". The operands are promoted to signed `int`. The suggested solution works but the explanation is wrong.