# Is snprintf() ALWAYS null terminating?

Tags: c, posix, libc

Is snprintf always null terminating the destination buffer?

In other words, is this sufficient:

```
char dst[10];

snprintf(dst, sizeof (dst), "blah %s", somestr);
```

or do you have to do like this, if somestr is long enough?

```
char dst[10];

somestr[sizeof (dst) - 1] = '\0';
snprintf(dst, sizeof (dst) - 1, "blah %s", somestr);
```

I am interested both in what the standard says and what some popular libc might do which is not standard behavior.

Comment: Do you mean to nul terminate somestr or dst in the second example?

Comment: @chux, Martin Ba covered that in the accepted answer. :)

Comment: @chux I think it was good, your comment just made it very clear that if dest i 0 long, nothing is written. I take every comment as a potential excuse to chat with fellow stackoverflowers. :)

Comment: @Prof. Falken Agree that comment was OK and explicit, but it was redundant with the answers - just missed that in my review.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8712996/193892 Visual Studio now supports *snprintf()*

Answer (score 92, accepted):

As the other answers establish: It [should](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

> [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) ... Writes the results to a character string buffer. (...)
>   will be terminated with a null character, unless buf_size is zero.

So all you have to take care is that you don't pass an zero-size buffer to it, because (obviously) it cannot write a zero to "nowhere".

---

However, **beware** that Microsoft's library <strike>*does not have* a function called `snprintf` but instead</strike> historically *only* had a function called `_snprintf` (note leading underscore) which *does not append* a terminating null. Here's the docs (VS 2012, ~~ VS 2013):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> ### Return Value
>
> Let len be the length of the formatted data string (not including the
>   terminating null). len and count are in bytes for _snprintf, wide
>   characters for _snwprintf.
>
> - If len < count, then len characters are stored in buffer, a
>     null-terminator is appended, and len is returned.
> - If len = count, then len characters are stored in buffer, **no
>     null-terminator is appended, and len is returned.**
> - If len > count, then count characters are stored in buffer, **no
>     null-terminator is appended, and a negative value is returned.**
>
> (...)

[Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) (VC14) apparently introduced the conforming `snprintf` function, but the legacy one with the leading underscore and the *non* null-terminating behavior is still there:

> The **`snprintf`** function truncates the output when len is greater
>   than or equal to count, by placing a null-terminator at
>   `buffer[count-1]`. (...)
>
> For all functions *other* than `snprintf`, if len = count, len
>   characters are stored in buffer, *no null-terminator is appended*,
>   (...)

Comment: What in the name of Aslan were the Microsoft engineers thinking when they introduced `_snprintf` which quietly **removes a key safety feature of `snprintf`** and permits the string to not be null-terminated?!

Comment: @ColinDBennett - it is weird and mighty annoying and I have no clue if anyone thought at all :-)

Comment: What's weird is that the documentation lies (or just not up-to-date). It does append a null-terminator.

Comment: in both the second and the third case if the buffer is large enough it writes the null after the count characters otherwise throws a runtime error.

Comment: @sekmet64 - your statement does not make sense. The *only* info about the buffer the function has is the `count`, so case 2+3 mean the buffer is too *small* (as far as the function is concerned). -- Although there is a C++ templateized version of this function (5th in the linked docs) - maybe that one has some additional features.

Comment: @sekmet64 - and indeed: "In C++, these functions have template overloads that invoke the **newer, secure counterparts** of these functions."

Comment: @MartinBa yeah sorry, what I tested was `template <size_t size> 
int _snprintf_s(char (&buffer)[size], size_t count, const char *format [, argument] ...);` and I should also mention that this happens only with /GS (Security Check) compile flag. That function knows size, count and length.

Comment: Beware that mingw64 used (uses?) the microsoft _snprintf implementation as "normal" snprintf unless specified otherwise https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-1000101

Comment: At first I read @ColinDBennett's (motivated) rant as: "What in the name of Asian", me being a non native English-speaker wondered what kind of idiom that was, and why Asia has anything to do with Microsoft :D. Still don't get the expression and what Narnias Lion has to do with anything. Enlighten me! :D

Comment: @Sajjon It's an admittedly silly (and perhaps totally original) exclamation of exasperation ( https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+name+of+God ) perhaps slightly as a minced oath ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath ). Another example might be "What in the name of Zeus...?!" ( https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/in-the-name-of-zeus.2132965/ )

Comment: @ColinDBennett: It matches strncpy. I can see a use for both functions.

Comment: Microsoft's _snprintf() predates any standard for snprintf(), I'm pretty sure, and therefore wasn't removing a safety feature, merely not implementing one.  Now, I'm sure there were (pre-standard) implementations of snprintf() that did always promise to nul-terminate (the character 0 is nul not null) and MSFT clearly didn't copy best-in-class .

Answer (score 23):

According to snprintf(3) manpage.

> The functions `snprintf()` and `vsnprintf()` write at most `size` bytes (including the trailing null byte ('\0')) to `str`.

So, yes, no need to terminate if size >= 1.

Comment: And thank god for that; this is the only sensible design. The whole point of the checked versions of these functions is to be *safe*, and it'd be terrible if you had to do all the termination malarkey by hand.

Comment: I would recommend testing it out on the platform(s) you're using before relying on this.  Even if it _should_ write the null byte, I know I've run into implementations that didn't (it might have been with MinGW, which used an older MS runtime).

Comment: I don't believe the phrase you cite actually means what you think it means.  As a native English speaker it clearly means that as long as the string, plus its nul-terminator, is at or under size, it will all be written.  But this sentence by itself is absolutely not describing what is written should size not be enough to write all.

Answer (score 15):

According to the C standard, unless the buffer size is 0, [`vsnprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/vfprintf.html) and [`snprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html) null terminates its output.

> The `snprintf()` function shall be equivalent to `sprintf()`, with the addition of the n argument which states the size of the buffer referred to by s. If n is zero, nothing shall be written and s may be a null pointer. Otherwise, output bytes beyond the n-1st shall be discarded instead of being written to the array, and a null byte is written at the end of the bytes actually written into the array.

So, if you need to know how big a buffer to allocate, use a size of zero, and you can then use a null pointer as the destination.  Note that I linked to the POSIX pages, but these explicitly say that there is not intended to be any divergence between Standard C and POSIX where they cover the same ground:

> The functionality described on this reference page is aligned with the ISO C standard. Any conflict between the requirements described here and the ISO C standard is unintentional. This volume of POSIX.1-2008 defers to the ISO C standard.

Be wary of the Microsoft version of [`vsnprintf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).  It definitely behaves differently from the standard C version when there is not enough space in the buffer (it returns -1 where the standard function returns the required length).  It is not entirely clear that the Microsoft version null terminates its output under error conditions, whereas the standard C version does.

However, note that Microsoft has changed the rules ([`vsnprintf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/vsnprintf-vsnprintf-vsnprintf-l-vsnwprintf-vsnwprintf-l?view=msvc-170)) since this answer was originally written:

> Beginning with the UCRT in Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 10, `vsnprintf` is no longer identical to `_vsnprintf`. The `vsnprintf` function conforms to the C99 standard; `_vnsprintf` is kept for backward compatibility with older Visual Studio code.

Similar comments apply to `snprintf()` and `sprintf()`.

Note also the answers to [Do you use the TR 24731 safe functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions) (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3xd30zz%28VS.80%29.aspx) for the Microsoft version of the `vsprintf_s()`) and the [Mac solution for the safe alternatives to unsafe C standard library functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169016/mac-solution-for-safe-alternatives-to-unsafe-c-c-standard-library-functions)

Comment: oh, wicked, never thought of that. On the other hand... :)

Comment: ah, I think MS vsprintf() bit me, and I picked up that - 1 habit

Answer (score 5):

Some older versions of SunOS did weird things with snprintf and might have not NUL-terminated the output and had return values that didn't match what everyone else was doing, but anything that has been released in the past 10 years have been doing what C99 says.

Comment: I notice that XP was released slightly more than 10 years ago. :-)

Comment: And this year it was obsoleted. :)

Answer (score 3):

The ambiguity starts from the C Standard itself. Both C99 and C11 have identical description of `snprintf` function. Here is the description from C99:

> **7.19.6.5 The `snprintf` function**
>   **Synopsis**
>   1   `#include <stdio.h>
>   int snprintf(char * restrict s, size_t n, const char * restrict format, ...);`
>   **Description**
>   2 The `snprintf` function is equivalent to `fprintf`, except that the output is written into an array (specified by argument `s`) rather than to a stream. If `n` is zero, nothing is written, and `s` may be a null pointer. Otherwise, output characters beyond the `n-1`st are
>   discarded rather than being written to the array, and a null character is written at the end of the characters actually written into the array. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.
>   **Returns**
>   3 The `snprintf` function returns the number of characters that would have been written had `n` been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative value if an encoding error occurred. Thus, the null-terminated output has been completely written if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than `n`.

**On the one hand** the sentence

> Otherwise, **output characters beyond the `n-1`st are discarded** rather than being written to the array, **and a null character is written at the end of the characters actually written** into the array

says that
*if (the `s` points to a 3-character-long array, and) `n` is 3, then **2 characters will be written, and the characters beyond the 2nd one are discarded**; then the **null character is written after those 2** (and the null character will be the 3rd character written)*.

And this I believe answers the original question.
**THE ANSWER:**
If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.
If `n` is 0 then nothing is written to the output
otherwise, if no encoding errors encountered, *the output is ALWAYS null-terminated* (*regardless of whether the output fits in the output array or not*; if not then some characters are discarded such that the output array is never overflown),
otherwise (if encoding errors are encountered) the output *can stay non-null-terminated*.

**On the other hand**
The last sentence

> Thus, the null-terminated output has been completely written if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than `n`

gives *ambiguity* (or my English is not good enough). I can interpret this sentence in at least two ways:
1. The output is **null-terminated** if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and **less than `n`** (which means that if the returned value is *not* less than `n`, i.e. the output (including the terminating null character) does not fit in the array, then the output *is not null-terminated*).
2. The output is **complete** (no characters have been discarded) if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and **less than `n`**.

---

I believe that the interpretation 1 above contradicts THE ANSWER, causes misunderstanding and lengthy discussions. That is why the last sentence describing the `snprintf` function needs a change in order to remove any ambiguity (which gives grounds for writing a Proposal to the C language Standard).
The example of non-ambiguous wording I believe can be taken from http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf (see `4)`), thanks to @"Martin Ba" for the link.

See also the question "[snprintf: Are there any C Standard Proposals/plans to change the description of this func?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50515162/snprintf-are-there-any-c-standard-proposals-plans-to-change-the-description-of)".

Comment: Your interpretation 1 does not seem at all plausible to me.  I parse that sentence as "The output (which is, incidentally, null-terminated) has been completely written if ..." which I can only understand as #2.

Comment: The negation of the sentence "null-terminated output has been completely written" is "null-terminated output has *not* been completely written". Nothing more. The negated sentence by itself does not imply that *anything* has been written (this includes incomplete null-terminated output, incomplete non-null-terminated output, or colourless green ideas).  Some other place in the standard says what exactly is written when output is incomplete, and *that place* states that the output is null terminated unless it's empty (n == 0).