# Using snprintf to avoid buffer overrun

Tags: c

> I dont understand why I am getting an output like this: StackOver↨< as snprintf should take care of null termination as expected output is StackOver. I am using devcpp IDE.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[10];
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(buffer));
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%s", "StackOverflow");
    printf("%s", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about checking the return value from `snprintf`

Comment: @EdHeal: you're not helping...

Comment: "StackOverflow" is 13 chars length, but your buffer only 10 chars . This is the reason why you have output like this.

Comment: @Ignat that is why the function `snprintf` is being used, which prevents buffer overflow.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - Why is that not helping? Checking the return value would help

Comment: It will return a negative value.

Comment: @user7375520 No it won't. It returns the number of characters successfully printed, which is less than `strlen("StackOverflow")`, which tells you it did not succeed.

Comment: In some versions of MSVC this function does not include a nul terminator if the formatted string exactly fits or overflows the size limit. It looks as though this is the case with your compiler too. It also returns a negative function value in overflow situations.

Comment: Small remark, for completeness, you might want to change `printf("%d\n", sizeof(buffer));` into `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(buffer));` since the return type for `sizeof` is `size_t`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks a lot!

Comment: *devcpp* is probably an IDE, not a compiler (or a C standard library). You need to look into the documentation of your C standard library & compiler. You might report a bug, if you are sure that you have found one.

Comment: FWIW, on Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64 with GCC 6.2, libc 2.24 your code behave as it should, and shows `StackOver` without a new line. I strongly suspect your C standard library is buggy.

Answer (score 3):

The [C Standard states](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) that the copied string shall be nul-terminated:

> **7.21.6.5  The `snprintf` function**
>
> ...
>
> **Description**
>
> The `snprintf` function is equivalent to `fprintf` , except that the
>   output is written into an array (specified by argument s ) rather than
>   to a stream.  If n is zero, nothing is written, and `s` may  be  a 
>   null  pointer.   Otherwise,  output  characters  beyond  the `n-1`st 
>   are discarded rather than being written to the array, **and a null
>   character is written at the end of  the  characters  actually  written
>   into  the  array**.  If copying  takes  place  between  objects that
>   overlap, the behavior is undefined.

It appears you are running with an outdated and/or buggy C runtime library as the `snprintf()` implementation doesn't seem to properly implement the required behavior.

Comment: MSVC's man page comments about the function suggest it previously worked like `strncpy` but with C99 no longer does.

Comment: @WeatherVane Nice.  C99 is nearly two decades old.

Comment: Yep, that's where MSVC is. OP's compiler may be that old too.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've wasted a lot of time checking snprintf the same way as you need to check strncpy. Good to hear it has moved on!

Answer (score -1):

This code is working fine for me. The buffer only has space for 10 characters so sprintf is only able to write the first 9 characters that you tell it to write ("StackOver"). At the tenth character it stores a terminating null character, since every C string must be null-terminated.

The only suggestion I would make is adding a newline when printing the string at the end:

```
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

The lack of a newline at the end might be the reason why your IDE is showing you that `↨` character.

If you want the buffer to fit "StackOverflow" you need to allocate it to something larger.

Comment: It didn't help. I dont know how come I am getting the similar output all the time?

Comment: You are supposed to get that output every time. There is no randomness involved. Maybe I didn't understand what you were *actually* trying to do?

Comment: @hugomg I tested it, and adding the newline removes a strange symbol for me in OSX terminal.

Comment: Is there any problem with my IDE?

Comment: @CareyGregory It tried with ur suggestion by adding a new line. Still getiing the same output. But if I run the program on some online C complier I am getting the expected output. I dont want to allocate a larger buffer just want to see how snprintf is not giving the expected result in this case. Thanks!

Comment: Expected result is "StackOver". It should print only 9 characters.

Comment: It is printing only 9 characters when I tested it. Are you taking about the "↨" bit?

Comment: That is my question: Why I'm getting output as "StackOver↨<"?

Comment: @user7375520 Your expectations are incorrect. As @WeatherVane commented on your question, not all implementations of `snprintf` will insert a null terminator in this case, which means you end up printing garbage.

Comment: @CareyGregory: snprintf is supposed to always include a null terminator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706936/

Comment: Maybe so, but it appears not to be happening here. Could be the IDE, I don't know, but clearly something is being printed that shouldn't be.

Comment: The problem is not with the IDE or the compiler. It is with the C standard library implementation of the original poster. OP should make a bug report (or switch to a better implementation, e.g. by using some recent Linux distribution)