# C++: How to use memcpy with pointer **?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I use this code:

```
memcpy(arr[i], arr1[i], sizeof(arr1[i]));
```

with definition:

```
double** arr;           // arr1 is difined the same way.
arr = new double*[row];
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
    arr[i] = new double[col];
    memcpy(arr[i], arr1[i], sizeof(arr1[i]));
}
```

I built it with command : `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -c arr.cpp` and had result:

warning: argument to 'sizeof' in 'void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)' call is the same pointer type 'double*' as the destination; expected 'double' or an explicit length [-Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess]

```
memcpy(arr[i], arr1[i], sizeof(arr1[i]));
                             ^
```

I don't understand what it is. Could you tell me how to make it work correctly?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2681061/69537

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A small visualization can help you to understand the warning better.

[image]

Suppose row = 2 and col = 2. Above picture shows visualization of `arr1[0]`.

In your code `memcpy(arr[i], arr1[i], sizeof(arr1[i]));` the `sizeof(arr1[i])` yields size of double* (as indicated by @πάντα ῥεῖ). As seen in the above picture, `arr1[0]` is a pointer to double and hence `sizeof(arr1[0])` can take a value of 4 or 8 depending upon whether you are running a 32 or 64 bit application.

If col = 2 then `arr1[0]` can hold two double values, namely `arr1[0][0]` and `arr1[0][1]` as shown in the picture. Since you want to copy an entire row, you will have to specify the length of bytes held by `arr1[0]` which can be achieved by `sizeof(double)*col` as indicated by @ToddChristensen or by `sizeof(arr1[i][0])*col`.

Since the warning you receive calls for the specification of an explicit length, you will have to use below `memcpy` in order for your copy operation to work correctly.

```
memcpy(arr[i], arr1[i], sizeof(arr1[i][0])*col);
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 9):

`sizeof(arr1[i])` yields the size of a `double*` pointer variable, not the actual size of the array you have allocated.

That warning is perfect, appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Try `sizeof(double) * col` instead.  `sizeof()` doesn't know what argument you passed to `new`.