# How to use printf in c to print integers

Tags: c

How do I printf integers? When I use:

```
int n = GetInt();

printf("%n \n", n);
```

I get the error that there was an unused variable and I can't compile it.

Comment: I wonder if this function is documented anywhere on the internet... nah, probably not.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you expect `"%n"` to work? A tip: If you're writing a call to a library function, *always* read the documentation for that function unless you're absolutely certain you know what you're doing. (And the space before the `\n` is probably unnecessary.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: I'm guessing it was a perceived association with the name of the variable... or a guess, and the OP chose "n" for "number".  I don't know...

Comment: Oh, and the code you've shown us shouldn't produce an "unused variable" warning, nor should such a warning prevent you from compiling the program (unless you're using something like `gcc -Werror`). You've got problems elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @EdS.: No offense, but what's the point of guessing how the OP might answer my question?

Comment: @KeithThompson: ...I don't know... I think I'm just bored.  I should move on.

Comment: Thanks for the help...I have no idea where to look for any of this, so I ask for help. And I just started learning programing and c language for that matter, today.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a replacement for your system's man pages.

Comment: I'd like to explain why I was confused. The I didn't understand that the "%s" or "%d" wasn't the variable itself but rather a way to display a variable (perhaps of different type) specified later in the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answers indicated, you normally print an `int` with the `%d` conversion specification, or optionally with the `%i` conversion specification.  You can also use `%o`, `%x` or `%X` (and `%u`), though technically there's a signed-to-unsigned conversion implied by doing so.

Note that `%n` is a valid conversion specification for [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) et al.  However, unlike all the other conversion specifications, the `%n` conversion specification is an output operation that takes a pointer to an `int` and it is used to find out how many characters have been written up to that point in the format string.  Therefore, you could use:

```
int n = GetInt();
int c;

printf("%d%n\n", n, &c);
printf("%d characters in number %d\n", c, n);
```

Note, too, that there is almost never any need for a space before a newline.

The [TR24731-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions) (or ISO/IEC 9899:2011 Annex K, Bounds Checking Interfaces) defines `printf_s()` et al, and explicitly outlaws the `%n` conversion specification because it often leads to problems precisely because it is an output parameter rather than an input parameter.

Answer (score 1):

A signed integer uses `%d` (or `%i`).

See also `man 3 printf` (on Unix-like systems) for the whole list of modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to use a format specifier corresponding to the integer you passed. The most common is `%d`. Try replacing the `%n` with a `%d`.

[Here's a more in depth explanation of all the format codes](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: Why do people keep downvoting with no explanation? It's so annoying.

Answer (score 0):

`int n;`

```
printf("get number:");
scanf("%d",&n);
scanf("%d",&n);
```

printf("your number is %d\n",n);
return 0;