# undefined reference to `strcpy_s' can't compile

Tags: c, reference, undefined, strcpy, tr24731

i follow the book and can't compile this example. Any suggestions?

```
  1 #define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
  2 #include <string.h>
  3 #include <stdio.h>
  4 
  5 
  6 int main(void)
  7 {
  8         char source[] = "Here we go...";
  9         char destination[50];
 10 
 11         if(strcpy_s(destination, sizeof(destination), source))
 12                 printf("An error occurred copying the string.n");
 13 
 14 
 15         return 0;
 16 }
```

error:

```
/tmp/ccc5KZDZ.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `strcpy_s'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/string.h/strcpy It might not be supported by your (g)libc.

Answer (score 6):

The `strcpy_s()` function is defined in TR 24731-1 (see [Do you use the TR 24731 'safe' functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions)), and also in optional Annex K of ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (the C 2011 standard).

You can test whether your implementation supports it with:

> `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` The integer constant 200509L, intended to indicate
>   conformance to this Technical Report.

(according to the TR).  Annex K simply says:

> An implementation that defines `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` shall conform to the
>   specifications in this annex.<sup>380)</sup>
>
> <sup>380)</sup> Implementations that do not define `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` are not required to conform to these
>   specifications.

*This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16700951/15168) indicates that the TC1 (Technical Corrigenda 1) for the C 2011 standard defines that `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` should be 201112L (Dec 2011) for the Annex K version of the functions.  I've not tracked whether there are differences between Annex K and TR 24731-1.*

So, you should be able to test whether your library supports `strcpy_s()` by testing `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__`, but it is optional.  There was apparently a statement by Ulrich Drepper that the GNU C Library would not support the TR 24731-1 functions; I don't know whether that still holds.

Also, be aware that the Microsoft interfaces to some of these functions is different from the standard interfaces to the same function (`vsnprintf_s()`, for example).  That limits their usefulness as a cross-platform portability tool.