# undefined reference to `strnlen_s', strncpy_s',strncat_s'

Tags: c

```
    length += strnlen_s(str[i],sizeof(str[i]));

//create array to hold all strings combined

char joke[length + strnlen_s(preamble, sizeof(preamble)) + 1];

if(strncpy_s(joke, sizeof(joke), preamble, sizeof(preamble)))
{
    printf("Error copying  preamble to joke.\n");
    return 1;
}

//Concatenate strings in joke

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < strCount; ++i)
{
    if(strncat_s(joke, sizeof(joke), str[i], sizeof(str[i])))
    {
```

---

```
joiningstring.c:32:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strnlen_s’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
joiningstring.c:38:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strncpy_s’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
joiningstring.c:48:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strncat_s’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
/tmp/ccBnGxvX.o: In function `main':
joiningstring.c:(.text+0x163): undefined reference to `strnlen_s'
joiningstring.c:(.text+0x188): undefined reference to `strnlen_s'
joiningstring.c:(.text+0x1fd): undefined reference to `strncpy_s'
joiningstring.c:(.text+0x251): undefined reference to `strncat_s'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Have you `#included` the relevant header file?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Given that OP has linker errors too, I'd say he's trying to compile a Windows-specific program on a Unix-like system.

Comment: Yes, the textbook, require the use of -std=c11. unfortunately I don't now to configure it. 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
#if defined __STDC_LIB_EXT1__
 printt("Optional functions are defined.\n");
#else
 printf("Optional functions are not defined.\n");
#endif
 return 0;
}

====================
Optional functions are not defined.

Answer (score 8):

The `strlen_s`, `strncpy_s` and `strncat_s` functions are Microsoft extensions to the standard C library. They are defined in the `string.h` header, and are part of the libraries automatically linked.

So, since the function appear to be undefined (you get `implicit declaration of function` errors), and not found (due to the `undefined reference` errors from the linker), I'd say that you either are trying to compile this code on a non-Microsoft system (in which case, I'd suggest using the alternatives functions `strlen`, `strncpy`, `strncat`) or forgot the include and asked the compiler to not include default library (then you should fix the code and the compiler invocation).

Comment: Actually, they are documented in TR 24731 and are now in Annex K (optional) of ISO/IEC 9899:2011, the C2011 standard.  They are not widely available off Microsoft, though.  See [Do you use the TR 24731 'safe' functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions) for more details.