# Array of pointer to char width typedef

Tags: c, pointers, char, malloc, typedef

i am trying to make a array of pointer to char.
I decided to use typedef definicion, but i have no clue what am doing wrong...

```
typedef struct _pp{
    char* a[10];
    int b;
}pp;

int main(){
  pp *taa = (pp* )malloc(sizeof(pp));
  taa->b = 2;
  printf("%d\n", taa->b);
  taa->a[1]=(char* )malloc(strlen("Peter")+1);
  strcpy((taa->*a[1]), "Peter");

  printf("%s\n", taa->*(a[1]));
  /*
```

/*That works*/

```
  int i;  
  int* a[5];
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    a[i]=(int* )malloc(sizeof(int));
    **(a+i)=i+100;
    printf("%d\n", **(a+i));
  */}
```

EDITED

Is that good practice?

```
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    taa->a[i]=(char* )malloc(strlen("Peter")+1);
    strncpy((taa->a[i]), "Peter", strlen("Peter"));
  }
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("%s\n", taa->a[i]);
  }
```

QUESTION 3) `taa->*a[1]` is equivalent to `ta.***(a + i)` ?

```
printf("%c",*taa->a[1]);  It dereference 'P' character, how i can get acces to 'e'?
```

`printf("%c",*(taa->a[1]+0));`

`printf("%c",*(taa->a[1]+1));`
That's the way...

Comment: Well, what error are you getting, and on what line of code?

Comment: Although C++ has the `->*` operator I don't think that it is available in C...

Comment: it is, well at least on my compiler ,

Comment: If this is C (as tagged), [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: @user2533527 What compiler are you using? Because http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Member_and_pointer_operators disagrees with what you say... It is available in C++ though and does something different.

Comment: I am casting, because it is transparent.

Comment: @nonsensickle I used to use Microsoft compiler on C 
and it eats the -> operator but I think you might be right about other compilers since Microsoft C compiler is actually C++ compiler.
also in Microsoft DDK I used to use -> operator .

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
strcpy((taa->a[1]), "Peter");
```

Also note that `[1]` is accessing the second element in the array; use `[0]` for the first. Also best to use `strncpy` or something "safe" which you pass the length of your char buffer (string) into to stop memory being scribbled on is good.

**Edit:**

Safe string functions that aren't standard:

[strlcpy](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/nonstandard/strlcpy)

[strcpy_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: `strcpy_s` is not standard C

Comment: @user4815162342: `strcpy_s()` is an optional part of C11 — ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (Annex K, normative).  However, the only platform where it is readily available is Microsoft Windows with MSVC.

Comment: I think that it applies only to the `gets()` function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29

Comment: @nonsensickle: What 'only applies to the `gets()` function'?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Point taken. Changed to strncpy!!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I read things quite literally. The wiki article only mentions `gets()`, although I would agree that it was "most likely" propagated to the rest I can't say for sure. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @nonsensickle The wiki article is not the standard - see [the actual standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), §K.3.7.1.3 (page 615).

Comment: @noelicus: About strncpy... I recommend not using it as a replacement for strcpy for performance reasons. strncpy will zero-fill the entire buffer. If this is something like an 8KB buffer for holding a URL, which is usually around 20 bytes, that is a big waste of time. Yes, it shows up in performance profiling. If you can use strlcpy or you can use snprintf.

Comment: @user4815162342 I'm aware it is not the standard but I wanted an actual reference. Thanks for providing it :)

Comment: See also [Do you use the TR 24731 'safe' functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions), where TR24731-1 was technical report that was a precursor to Annex K in the 2011 standard. Annex K covers a lot of functions.  The `gets()` function is simply eliminated from §7.21.7 (where `fgets()` is still documented).  The `gets_s()` function is documented in §K.3.5.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy` function needs a `char*` type for first argument.
in your `pp struct` you have ten `char*`s. you are accessing your second `char*` with `taa->a[1]`. So removing `*` after `->` will give you what you need.
This works fine:

```
strcpy((taa->a[1]), "Peter");
```

Comment: You mean aside from `->*` being illegal syntax in C?

Comment: taa->*a[1] is equal to ta.***(a + i) i thing...   There are three level of decrement..

Comment: @nonsensickle, as i remember, [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) complains about `->*` but `*taa->a[i]` is ok. @XosLamoo I could not figure out what `***(a+i)` is about this subject.

Comment: @FredrickGauss You are correct. Sorry, it seems I forgot my manners. I've been saying it is not C without offering an alternative. Yes, you are meant to use `*taa->a[i]` to dereference `a[i]`. The `->` operator has higher precedence than `*` so it is equivalent to `*(taa->a[i])` which is what I think is desired. The `->*` operator is used for member function pointers in C++. This http://aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Oct_1999.pdf article should give an example as to what the `->*` operator is used for in C++.

Comment: I am meant to use `*taa->a[i]` to dereference `a[i][0]` that is `taa->a[i][0]` for single `char`acter access. But for the question, it is the address of the character array so simply `taa->a[i]`.

Comment: @fredrick-gauss  This is not working.                         `while(*taa->a[i++])
    printf("%c",*taa->a[i]);` How to dereference single char?

Comment: you can not dereference when `i = 10` in `while(*taa->a[10])...`

Comment: @FredrickGauss printf("%c",*(taa->a[1]+0));

printf("%c",*(taa->a[1]+1)); That's the way?

Comment: `taa->a[i][1]` or `*(taa->a[1] + 1)` will lead to the `'e'` in the `"Peter"` as of second character.