# Trouble using char in scanf in a structure

Tags: c, arrays, char, structure

I'm a student studying C, and seem to be stuck when using Structures and Arrays to read in characters as part of the array.

When I run the code, it skips over the char scanf and will not read in any characters. There is no problem reading in integers etc.

For example (This is an example, my code is much longer but I know there's a problem here). Is the scanf part that reads in the name correct?

```
struct stud s[5];
int i = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    fflush(stdout);
    s[i].no = i + 1;
    printf("\nStud number %d\n", s[i].no);
    printf("Enter name:");
    scanf_s("%c", &s[i].name);
    printf("Enter grade: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &s[i].grade);
    printf("Successfully added to grade book\n");
}
```

I declared them below:

```
struct stud {
    int no;
    char name;
    int grade;
};
```

It would be great if someone could point me in the correct direction?

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: this line: printf("Enter name:"); because only one char will be read, probably should be: printf("Enter first Letter of Name:");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you should create a `char` array of a reasonable size and use `%s` as mentioned by @iharob in his answer if you want to enter more than 1 character for a student. If you want `name` to be a `char`,then change

```
scanf_s("%c", &s[i].name);
```

To

```
scanf_s(" %c", &s[i].name, 1);
```

The space before `%c` skips all kinds of blanks(like newlines and spaces) present in the `stdin` and `%c` will then scan a non-whitespace character.

Comment: `scanf_s(" %c")` needs 2 following arguments

Comment: I didn't know that! But [this site](http://code.wikia.com/wiki/Scanf_s) does not mention about 2 arguments. If that site is wrong,then is `scanf_s(" %c",&s[i].name,1);` right?

Comment: A [ms sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) uses `scanf_s("%4c", &c, _countof(c));`  There are various details surrounding use of `scanf_s` like the type of `_countof(c)`.

Comment: Ok - This I think is the correct way, I recall a lecturer telling us this: scanf_s(" %c", &s[i].name,1);

Comment: How do you add something in a variable, e.g. s[i].gradetotal = s[i].grade * 50;. Is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: @Meh , There isn't a variable named `gradetotal` in the structure. So you cannot do that. BTW,you can accept my answer if it helped.

Comment: @chux The problem is that `gradetotal` is defined in my programme. `s[i].gradetotal = 0.0000` when I print it after multiplying it by 50. I've tried making everything int or float etc but the answer is 0.0000 when I print `s[i].gradetotal` after the calculation. How do you multiply or divide something in this scenario?

Comment: @Meh ,Try `s[i].gradetotal = s[i].grade * 50.0;`

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare `name` as a `char` array

```
struct room {
    int no;
    char name[32]; /* pick a reasonable size */
    int grade;
};
```

And then this

```
scanf_s("%c",&s[i].name);
```

would change to

```
scanf_s("%s",s[i].name, _countof(s[i].name));
```

and since there is no guarantee that the `name` would be `31` characters length, you have to specify a field length like this

```
scanf_s("%31s",s[i].name, _countof(s[i].name));
```

the length should be the `sizeOfArray - 1` since c strings need to mark the end of the string with a null byte `'\0'`, and `scanf_s` will append that byte to the read string.

If you don't specify the field length and it turns out that there are more than characters than requested by `_countof(s[i].name)` then nothing is read, for more information read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx).

Comment: Note that [`_countof()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773.aspx) is not standard C (a Microsoft extension), and while `scanf_s()` is defined in Annex K of the C11 standard, it is not widely implemented (it is available with Microsoft and not usually available with Unix-like systems).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Annex K `scanf_s` and MS `scanf_s` are incompatible. The size parameters for the Annex K version are of type `size_t`, and `int` for the MS version. In a variadic function.

Comment: @mafso: I wish I could say I was [surprised](http://stackoverflow.com/a/373911/15168).  I knew of issues with `snprintf_s()`; I wasn't specifically aware of issues with `scanf_s()`.

Comment: `_countof` has type `int`, not `size_t`, so it is equivalent to `(int)(sizeof array/sizeof *array)`. `_countof` is correct for MS `scanf_s` and `sizeof array/sizeof *array` for Annex K `scanf_s` (I don't know if there are common platforms implementing it at all). My advice is not to use these functions at all. They are non-portable, almost always used wrongly (in questions and answers on SO, I haven't seen real-world code using them), and solve too few problems of the standard functions.

Comment: @mafso, ok then shuold I leave it in the comments or do I fix the answer?

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe ask OP if she wants to tag as Windows. Or mention portability problems in the answer (and maybe suggest `scanf` or something else if you like). Or just leave it as-is; at least, the first correct use of `scanf_s` I've seen on SO for a while.

Comment: @mafso Seems like [`_countof` has type `size_t` in newer versions of VS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773(v=vs.140).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The `%c` will not the characters because the characters will be present in `stdin`,  and you have to skip the characters.

```
scanf_s("%c", &s[i].name);
```

if the last character in the previous is `\n` the `%c` will take the `\n` as input.
You have to change the code, just give a space before the `%c`.

```
scanf_s(" %c", &s[i].name);
```

This will flush the white space characters in the `stdin` and it will get the input.