# undefined reference to 'mbstowcs_s'

Tags: c

This is my code. I want to test function mbstowcs_s.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <assert.h>


int main()
{
    char MultiByteStr[20] = "a中";
    wchar_t WideByteStr[20];

    printf("%s\n", MultiByteStr);

    char* LocaleInfo = setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    printf("%s\n", LocaleInfo);

    // required length of WideByteStr
    size_t WideStrLen = 0;
    mbstowcs_s(&WideStrLen, NULL, 0, MultiByteStr, 0);
    assert(WideStrLen < 20);
    mbstowcs_s(NULL, WideByteStr, 20, MultiByteStr, WideStrLen);
    WideByteStr[WideStrLen] = L'\0';
    wprintf(L"%ls\n", WideByteStr);

    return 0;
}
```

I test this code on windows platform successfully, but failed on linux platform. Below is the error message.

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:20:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mbstowcs_s’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     mbstowcs_s(&WideStrLen, NULL, 0, MultiByteStr, 0);
     ^
/tmp/ccqzP6HF.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `mbstowcs_s'
test.c:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference to `mbstowcs_s'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: It is a [C11 function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbstowcs).  You probably ought to tell your compiler about it.

Comment: This is a `C11` from the optional Annex K, so it might not exist on your platform. If it would, you'd still have to enable Annex K with the appropriate macro before all `#include`.

Comment: See [Do you use the TR-24731 “safe” functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/372980/15168) for more information about the `_s` functions and Unix.

Comment: The control macro is `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__`.  The result of not defining it at all is implementation-defined, so on some implementations you may not in fact need to define it.  With that said, if you use the Annex-K functions then you *should* define it -- to `1` --, before any system headers are directly or indirectly `#include`d.  That way, you have the desired semantics on *every* conforming C11 implementation that in fact supports these optional features.  Not all do support them, however, so for greatest portability, you should not rely on the system to provide them.

Comment: The is no `man` page entry on linux for `mbstowcs_s` so you can expect that the function (really a windows/MSDN function) to not be found on linux