# Why does reopening stdout to a newly-allocated console occasionally fail?

Tags: c, winapi, handle, freopen

Consider this program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE")

int main(void) {
    if (!FreeConsole()) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "FreeConsole failed", NULL, MB_ICONHAND);
        return 1;
    }
    if (!AllocConsole()) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "AllocConsole failed", NULL, MB_ICONHAND);
        return 1;
    }
    FILE* newstdout;
    if (freopen_s(&newstdout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout)) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "freopen_s failed", NULL, MB_ICONHAND);
        return 1;
    }
    if (newstdout != stdout) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "freopen_s did something wonky", NULL, MB_ICONHAND);
        return 1;
    }
    puts("1");
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Look for 1 then press OK", NULL, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Steps to reproduce: create a new empty C/C++ project in Visual Studio 2019, go to Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System and change SubSystem to Not Set, then add the above code to the project in a new file called `Source.c`.

Most of the time I run it, it opens a new console with the number 1 in it, like it's supposed to, but sometimes it fails. If I used "Start Without Debugging" (Ctrl+F5) to run it, it fails about 1 run out of 30, with my "freopen_s failed" message. If I used "Start Debugging" (F5) to run it, it also fails about 1 run out of 10, with `_NtClose` throwing an exception that says "An invalid handle was specified", with a stack trace pointing at my call to `freopen_s`.

Why does this intermittent failure happen? Am I breaking one of the rules of the Windows API, either in the C code or in the project configuration?

Things I tried so far that didn't change the behavior:

- Removing the line with `#pragma`
- Using `CON` in place of `CONOUT$`
- `freopen_s`ing `stdout` to `NUL` before calling `FreeConsole`

Comment: Hmmm. Why `"CONOUT$"` instead of `"CON"`?

Comment: @Joshua Because that's what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9047596/7509065), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15547699/7509065), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67461918/7509065) used. Although now that you said that, I did just try switching to `CON` and it still did the exact same thing.

Comment: Why would you ever want FreeConsole followed by AllocConsole?

Comment: @Anders: To detach from the calling process's console and have your own. I've done this in Win32 code (no C standard library)

Comment: @Joshua That is what the `start` command is for :). `FreeConsole` assumes that you are done with consoles from then on.

Comment: @Anders [The MSDN documentation for FreeConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole) says "After a process calls FreeConsole, it can call the AllocConsole function to create a new console or AttachConsole to attach to another console."

Answer (score 1):

This is messed up, it's not your fault. `FreeConsole()` proceeds to destroy the old console and take down the handle with it. This invalidates `stdout` asynchronously.

You really want to do something like this. Note that you really do need to do `stdin` and `stderr` as well as `stdout` or bad things can happen later.

```
    // Change the handle of stdout so that we can destroy the old one.
    FILE* newstdout;
    if (freopen_s(&newstdout, "NUL", "w", stdout)) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "freopen_s failed", NULL, MB_ICONHAND);
        return 1;
    }
    if (!FreeConsole()) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "FreeConsole failed", NULL, MB_ICONHAND);
        return 1;
    }
    if (!AllocConsole()) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "AllocConsole failed", NULL, MB_ICONHAND);
        return 1;
    }
    // Now we can point stdout at it.
    if (freopen_s(&newstdout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout)) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "freopen_s failed", NULL, MB_ICONHAND);
        return 1;
    }
    if (newstdout != stdout) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "freopen_s did something wonky", NULL, MB_ICONHAND);
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even when I do switch `stdout` to `NUL` first like that, the same thing still happens.