# How to format a C-string platform independently with va_lists?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

If I compile my code containing [`vsnprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf) on VS2015 it complains about :

```
warning C4996: 'vsnprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe.  
               Consider using vsnprintf_s instead.
```

If i use [`vsnprintf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/d3xd30zz.aspx) then gcc fails compiling it.

How to solve this? I would like to compile the code without (suppressed) warnings and platform independent.

Using C++ streams is not possible because the `va_list` and format string is created in C-Code.

Comment: Write your own implementation of vsnprintf? Alternatively, I think you should switch off the warning (you will get it from things like memcpy).

Comment: This is just Microsoft warning you that you are being unfaithful and thinking about other platforms. Their opinion, not mine.

Comment: @YSC it is in some kind of c wrapping code. so using streams is not a valid solution because the format string and varargs are from the c-world

Comment: Note [Do you use the TR-24731 "safe" functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions) – and in particular my answer which notes that the differences between `vsnprintf_s()` and `vsnprintf()` are significant.  It also notes that in modern MS Visual Studio, `vsnprintf()` differs from `_vsnprintf()`.  Much the simplest is to suppress the warnings from MS and use (standard) `vsnprintf()`.

Comment: I'd be happy to have feedback on my answer, dear OP.

Answer (score 1):

Well, write MS-specific code:

```
#ifndef _MSC_VER
#define vsnprintf_s(buf, size, count, format, list) std::vsnprintf(buf, size, format, list)
#endif // _MSC_VER

char buf[64];
vsnprintf_s(buf, sizeof(buf), _TRUNCATE, "%s...", valist);
```

Comment: doesn't even have to be a #define

Comment: @peterchen I'm reluctant to define a C++ identifier named `vsnprintf_s` just in case there are distros defining it in their C++ implementation. But you're right.